# What is the difference between memmove and memcpy?

Tags: c, memcpy, memmove

What is the difference between `memmove` and `memcpy`? Which one do you usually use and how?

Comment: Note the problems that might arise: https://lwn.net/Articles/414467/

Answer (score 178, accepted):

With `memcpy`, the destination cannot overlap the source at all. With `memmove` it can. This means that `memmove` might be very slightly slower than `memcpy`, as it cannot make the same assumptions.

For example, `memcpy` might always copy addresses from low to high. If the destination overlaps after the source, this means some addresses will be overwritten before copied. `memmove` would detect this and copy in the other direction - from high to low - in this case. However, checking this and switching to another (possibly less efficient) algorithm takes time.

Comment: when using memcpy, how can I guarantee that the src and dest addresses don't overlap? Should I personally make sure that src and dest do not overlap?

Comment: @Alcott, don't use memcpy if you don't know that they don't overlap - use memmove instead. When there is no overlap, memmove and memcpy are equivalent (although memcpy might be very, very, very slightly faster).

Comment: You can use 'restrict' keyword if you are working with long arrays and want to protect your copying process. For example if you method takes as parameters input and output arrays and you must verify that user does not pass the same address as input and output. Read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c

Comment: @DanielHsH 'restrict' is a promise you make the compiler; it is not _enforced_ by the compiler. If you put 'restrict' on your arguments and do, in fact, have overlap (or more generally, access the restricted data from pointer derived from multiple places), the behavior of the program is undefined, weird bugs will happen, and the compiler will usually not warn you about it.

Comment: @bdonlan It's not just a promise to the compiler, it's a requirement for your caller. It's a requirement that is not enforced but if you violate a requirement, you cannot complain if you get unexpected results. Violating a requirement is undefined behavior, just like `i = i++ + 1` is undefined; the compiler doesn't forbid you to write exactly that code but the result of that instruction can be anything and different compilers or CPUs will show different values here.

Comment: Looking at these comments, it looks like always use memmove.

Comment: @Mecki "not enforced" and "requirement" don't go together. It seems you're saying the same thing as bdonlan once we strip the first two contradictory sentences away.

Comment: @iheanyi They do go together as requirement means "it is required to do it that way if you want to have correct results" but getting correct results is **not enforced**. Of course you can write code that produces incorrect results if you like.

Comment: @Mecki I disagree. If that's the definition of "requirement", then it means nothing. You can write code that doesn't compile too if you'd like. There's no compiler that forces anyone to do anything they don't want to do.

Comment: @iheanyi No, you don't. You just repeated what I've said. A requirement in behavior does not mean that you cannot behave in a different way, it only means that behaving a different way has consequences. It is a requirement to follow the law but you can also violate it. If something is made in such a way, that you cannot violate it, then no requirement is necessary as there is no choice; you have to do it in the only way possible so what would be the requirement then? Not doing it that way means not doing it at all.

Comment: @Mecki then I don't see the difference between your comment and bdonlan. It seems you are saying the same thing. Restrict is a promise made to the compiler. But the compiler will let you violate that promise with potentially undefined results. Replace "promise" with "requirement" and you are saying the same thing.

Answer (score 38):

`memmove` can handle overlapping memory, `memcpy` can't.

Consider

```
char[] str = "foo-bar";
memcpy(&str[3], &str[4], 4); // might blow up
```

Obviously the source and destination now overlap, we're overwriting
"-bar" with "bar". It's undefined behavior using `memcpy` if the source
and destination overlap so in this case we need `memmove`.

```
memmove(&str[3], &str[4], 4); // fine
```

Comment: @ultraman: Because it MAY have been implemented using low level assembley that requires that memory does not overlap. If it does you could for example generate a signal or hardware exception to the processor that aborts the application. The documentation specifies that it does not handle the condition, but the standard does not specify what will happen when these conditions are vialoated (this is known as undefined behavior). Undefined behavior can do anything.

Comment: with gcc 4.8.2 , Even memcpy also accepts overlapping source and destination pointers and working fine.

Comment: @jagsgediya Sure it might. But since memcpy is documented to not support this, you should not rely on that implementation specific behavior, that's why memmove() exist. It might be different in another version of gcc. It might be different if gcc inlines the memcpy instead of calling out to memcpy() in glibc, it might be different on an older or newer version of glibc and so on.

Comment: From practice, it seems the memcpy and memmove did the same thing. Such a deep undefined behavior.

Answer (score 26):

Assuming you would have to implement both, the implementation could look like that:

```
void memmove ( void * dst, const void * src, size_t count ) {
    if ((uintptr_t)src < (uintptr_t)dst) {
        // Copy from back to front

    } else if ((uintptr_t)dst < (uintptr_t)src) {
        // Copy from front to back
    }
}

void memcpy ( void * dst, const void * src, size_t count ) {
    if ((uintptr_t)src != (uintptr_t)dst) {
        // Copy in any way you want
    }
}
```

And this should pretty well explain the difference. `memmove` always copies in such a way, that it is still safe if `src` and `dst` overlap, whereas `memcpy` just doesn't care as the documentation says when using `memcpy`, the two memory areas **must not** overlap.

E.g. if `memcpy` copies "front to back" and the memory blocks are aligned as this

```
[---- src ----]
            [---- dst ---]
```

copying the first byte of `src` to `dst` already destroys the content of the last bytes of `src` before these have been copied. Only copying "back to front" will lead to correct results.

Now swap `src` and `dst`:

```
[---- dst ----]
            [---- src ---]
```

In that case it's only safe to copy "front to back" as copying "back to front" would destroy `src` near its front already when copying the first byte.

You may have noticed that the `memmove` implementation above doesn't even test if they actually do overlap, it just checks their relative positions, but that alone will make the copy safe. As `memcpy` usually uses the fastest way possible to copy memory on any system, `memmove` is usually rather implemented as:

```
void memmove ( void * dst, const void * src, size_t count ) {
    if ((uintptr_t)src < (uintptr_t)dst
        && (uintptr_t)src + count > (uintptr_t)dst
    ) {
        // Copy from back to front

    } else if ((uintptr_t)dst < (uintptr_t)src
        && (uintptr_t)dst + count > (uintptr_t)src
    ) {
        // Copy from front to back

    } else {
        // They don't overlap for sure
        memcpy(dst, src, count);
    }
}
```

Sometimes, if `memcpy` always copies "front to back" or "back to front", `memmove` may also use `memcpy` in one of the overlapping cases but `memcpy` may even copy in a different way depending on how the data is aligned and/or how much data is to be copied, so even if you tested how `memcpy` copies on your system, you cannot rely on that test result to be always correct.

What does that mean for you when deciding which one to call?

1. Unless you know for sure that `src` and `dst` don't overlap, call `memmove` as it will always lead to correct results and is usually as fast as that is possible for the copy case you require.
2. If you know for sure that `src` and `dst` don't overlap, call `memcpy` as it won't matter which one you call for the result, both will work correctly in that case, but `memmove` will never be faster than `memcpy` and if you are unlucky, it may even be slower, so you can only win calling `memcpy`.

Comment: Note that the result of relational comparing pointers to different objects/arrays is unspecified. So there is no way to safely detect if two objects overlay with each other. In fact, the typical implementation of `memmove` copies data from front to back if `dst < src` otherwise copies data from back to front. It is safe because if there's overlay, the result is defined(and correct) so the behavior is safe, otherwise if there's no overlay, the result is unspecified but copying in both directions is safe.

Answer (score 23):

From the [memcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) man page.

> The memcpy() function copies n bytes
>   from memory area src to memory area
>   dest. The memory areas should not
>   overlap. Use [memmove](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove)(3) if the memory
>   areas do overlap.

Answer (score 12):

The main difference between `memmove()` and `memcpy()` is that in `memmove()` a *buffer* - temporary memory - is used, so there is no risk of overlapping. On the other hand, `memcpy()` directly copies the data from the location that is pointed by the *source* to the location pointed by the *destination*. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

Consider the following examples:

1. ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int main (void)
   {
       char string [] = "stackoverflow";
       char *first, *second;
       first = string;
       second = string;

       puts(string);
       memcpy(first+5, first, 5);
       puts(first);
       memmove(second+5, second, 5);
       puts(second);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   As you expected, this will print out:

   ```
   stackoverflow
   stackstacklow
   stackstacklow
   ```
2. But in this example, the results will not be the same:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int main (void)
   {
       char string [] = "stackoverflow";
       char *third, *fourth;
       third = string;
       fourth = string;

       puts(string);
       memcpy(third+5, third, 7);
       puts(third);
       memmove(fourth+5, fourth, 7);
       puts(fourth);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   stackoverflow
   stackstackovw
   stackstackstw
   ```

It is because "memcpy()" does the following:

```
1.  stackoverflow
2.  stacksverflow
3.  stacksterflow
4.  stackstarflow
5.  stackstacflow
6.  stackstacklow
7.  stackstacksow
8.  stackstackstw
```

Comment: But, it seems the output you mentioned is reversed !!

Comment: When I run the same program , I get the following result :  stackoverflow
stackstackstw
stackstackstw // means there is NO difference in output between memcpy and memmove

Comment: "is that in "memmove()", a buffer - a temporary memory - is used;" Is not true. it says "as if" so it just has to behave so, not that it has to be that way. Thats indeed relevant as most memmove implementations just do a XOR-swap.

Comment: I don't think the implementation of `memmove()` is required to use a buffer.  It's perfectly entitled to move in-place (as long as each read completes before any write to the same address).

Answer (score 10):

One (`memmove`) handles overlapping destinations the other (`memcpy`) doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

simply from the ISO/IEC:9899 standard it is well described.

> 7.21.2.1 The memcpy function
>
> [...]
>
> 2 The memcpy function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the
> object pointed to by s1. **If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.**

And

> 7.21.2.2 The memmove function
>
> [...]
>
> 2 The memmove function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the
> object pointed to by s1. Copying takes place **as if the n characters from the object
> pointed to by s2 are first copied into a temporary array of n characters that does not
> overlap** the objects pointed to by s1 and s2, and then the n characters from the
> temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by s1.

Which one I usually use acording to the question, depends on what functionallity I need.

In plain text `memcpy()` doesn't allow `s1` and `s2` to overlap, while `memmove()` does.

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious ways to implement `mempcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)` (ignoring the return value):

1. ```
   for (char *p=src, *q=dest;  n-->0;  ++p, ++q)
       *q=*p;
   ```
2. ```
   char *p=src, *q=dest;
   while (n-->0)
       q[n]=p[n];
   ```

In the first implementation, the copy proceeds from low to high addresses, and in the second, from high to low.  If the range to be copied overlaps (as is the case when scrolling a framebuffer, for example), then only one direction of operation is correct, and the other will overwrite locations that will subsequently be read from.

A `memmove()` implementation, at its simplest, will test `dest<src` (in some platform-dependent way), and execute the appropriate direction of `memcpy()`.

User code can't do that of course, because even after casting `src` and `dst` to some concrete pointer type, they don't (in general) point into the same object and so can't be compared.  But the standard library can have enough platform knowledge to perform such a comparison without causing Undefined Behaviour.

---

Note that in real life, implementations tend to be significantly more complex, to gain the maximum performance from larger transfers (when alignment permits) and/or good data cache utilisation.  The code above is just to make the point as simply as possible.

Answer (score 0):

memmove can deal with overlapping source and destination regions, while memcpy cannot. Among the two, memcpy is much more efficient. So, better to USE memcpy it if you can.

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yr1YnOVG-4g Dr. Jerry Cain, (Stanford Intro Systems Lecture - 7) Time: 36:00

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28624068/2410359) says "possibly a smidge faster" and provides quantitative data indicating only a slight difference.  This answer asserts one is "much more efficient". How much more efficient have you found the faster one to be?    BTW: I assume you mean `memcpy()` and not `memcopy()`.

Comment: The comment is made based on the lecture of Dr. Jerry Cain. I would request you listen to his lecture at time 36:00, only 2-3 minutes will suffice.

And thanks for the catch. :D