# C++ restrict qualifier on array reference

Tags: c++, optimization

what is the proper way to give `__restrict__`qualifier to two-dimensional array reference?
for example:

```
void function(double (&)[3][3]);
```

as far as I can tell, `g++` compiles the following (but no performance difference):

```
void function(double (& __restrict__)[3][3]);
```

is that correct?

full segment:

```
template<class A, class B, class C>
static void
multiply(const A (&a)[L][L], const B (&b)[L][L],
        C (&c)[L][L]) {
// C (&__restrict__ c)[L][L]) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < L; ++j) {
        // C __restrict__ *cj = c[j];
        for (size_t k = 0; k < L; ++k) {
            double b_jk = b[j][k];
            for (size_t i = 0; i < L; ++i) {
                c[j][i] += a[k][i]*b_jk;
                // cj[i] += a[k][i]*b_jk;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no references in C, so I removed the C tag.  What compiler supports this `__restrict__` in C++ (or C, for that matter)?  It's not a part of standard C++.

Comment: What James, said. References are C++ only and `restrict` (no underscores) is C only. If you are trying to use a C or C++ extension you should state your environment.

Comment: @James gcc, xlc, icc.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c

Answer (score 0):

`__restrict__` can only be used with pointers. It's possible to simulate a two-dimensional array using a pointer, though. Like `some_array[x*w + y]` instead of `some_array[x][y]`, where some_array is defined as `double *some_array[w]`. I think that should work...

But honestly, why do you even need restrict?

Comment: Of course, you'll have to take care of allocating enough space for the pointer.

Comment: because C++ assumes alias in pointers and as far as I can tell in this particular case.

Comment: ACTUALLY you can have restricted references. It just depends on your compiler. GCC will accept the `__restrict__` specifier on references: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html

Comment: `__restrict` or `__restrict__` is perfect valid for references. If often use `__restrict` in combination with `__builtin_assume_aligned` to hint the compiler that it can vectorize and avoid generating assembly for both 8-byte and 16-byte aligned arguments