# compiler nested loop optimization for sequential memory access.

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, loops, compiler-construction

I came across a strange performance issue in a matrix multiply benchmark (matrix_mult in Metis from the [MOSBENCH](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/mosbench/) suite). The benchmark was optimized to tile the data such that the active working set was 12kb (3 tiles of 32x32 ints) and would fit into the L1 cache. To make a long story short, swapping the inner two most loops had a performance difference of almost 4x on certain array input sizes (4096, 8192) and about a 30% difference on others. The problem essentially came down to accessing elements sequentially versus in a stride pattern. Certain array sizes I think created a bad stride access that generated a lot cache line collisions. The performance difference is noticeably less when changing from 2-way associative L1 to an 8-way associative L1.

My question is why doesn't gcc optimize loop ordering to maximize sequential memory accesses?

Below is a simplified version of the problem (note that performance times are highly dependent on L1 configuration. The numbers indicated below are from 2.3 GHZ AMD system with 64K L1 2-way associative compiled with -O3).

```
N = ARRAY_SIZE // 1024
int* mat_A = (int*)malloc(N*N*sizeof(int));
int* mat_B = (int*)malloc(N*N*sizeof(int));
int* mat_C = (int*)malloc(N*N*sizeof(int));

// Elements of mat_B are accessed in a stride pattern of length N
// This takes 800 msec  
for (int t = 0; t < 1000; t++) 
   for (int a = 0; a < 32; a++) 
      for (int b = 0; b < 32; b++)
         for (int c = 0; c < 32; c++) 
            mat_C[N*a+b] += mat_A[N*a+c] * mat_B[N*c+b];

// Inner two loops are swapped
// Elements are now accessed sequentially in inner loop
// This takes 172 msec  
for (int t = 0; t < 1000; t++) 
   for (int a = 0; a < 32; a++) 
      for (int c = 0; c < 32; c++) 
         for (int b = 0; b < 32; b++)
            mat_C[N*a+b] += mat_A[N*a+c] * mat_B[N*c+b];
```

Comment: Because it's very hard to prove for the compiler that such a change doesn't change the semantics of the operation.

Comment: maybe you find it interesting to google gcc+graphite, which was a now merged branch for loop transformations based on a polyhedral model. There's somewhere a list of possible transformations.

Comment: I would think that since integer addition is commutative that it would be fairly simple for a compiler to prove that the operation is invariant to looper ordering. I'm wondering what it is then about the code example that makes it non-trivial to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

1. gcc might not be able to prove that the pointers don't overlap. If you are fine using non   standard extensions you could try using [__restrict](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html).
2. gcc doesn't take full advantage of your architecture to avoid the necessity to recompile for every processor. Using the option [-march](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#i386-and-x86_002d64-Options) with the appropriate value for your system might help.

Comment: It's worth noting that restrict _is_ standard for C99, just not for C++.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c

Comment: @torek I know, just wanted to make clear that it's a non-standard extension but supported by many compilers.

Answer (score 0):

gcc has a bunch of optimizations that just do what you want.

Look up the -floop-strip-mine and -floop-block compiler options.

Quote from the manual:

> Perform loop blocking transformations on loops. Blocking strip mines
>   each loop in the loop nest such that the memory accesses of the
>   element loops fit inside caches. The strip length can be changed using
>   the loop-block-tile-size parameter.

Comment: Thanks, though the problem isn't due to the inner loops not fitting in cache, as that optimization was already done by hand in the code. The inner loops only have a 12kb data footprint. 3*1024 int values.