# Compiler error involving restrict keyword

Tags: c++, restrict, restrict-qualifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the restrict keyword mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c)

I'm trying to install [QMCPACK](http://code.google.com/p/qmcpack/) on OS X 10.8.2 and I'm getting a lot of errors like this:

```
bspline_base.h:95:17: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
void *restrict coefs;
              ^
              ;
```

I am unfamiliar with the restrict keyword but I feel like this may be some other kind of problem, because this is a popular code that compiles for other people.

Here is the full context of that code:

```
typedef struct
{
  spline_code sp_code;
  type_code   t_code;
  void *restrict coefs;
} Bspline;
```

Comment: About restrict, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c. It is not a keyword of the C++ language (which you tagged), as the first answer points out.

Answer (score 2):

`restrict` is not a *keyword* in standard *C++*. The code will only compile in a compiler that supports the `restrict` extension.

`restrict` **is** a *keyword* in *C99*. So if you use a *C99* compiler it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`restrict` is only available in C mode. `clang++` will need `__restrict` - add `-Drestrict=__restrict` to compiler flags.