# How to speed up a C++ sparse matrix manipulation?

Tags: c++, performance, eigen

I have a small script for manipulating a sparse matrix in C++. It works perfectly fine except taking too much time. Since I'm doing this manipulation over and over, it is critical to speed it up. I appreciate any idea.Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
#include <iostream>     /* cout, fixed, scientific */
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>      /* SJW 08/09/2010 */
#include <fstream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

SparseMatrix<double> MatMaker (int n1, int n2, double prob)
{
   MatrixXd A = (MatrixXd::Random(n1, n2) + MatrixXd::Ones(n1, n2))/2;
   A = (A.array() > prob).select(0, A);
   return A.sparseView();
}

////////////////This needs to be optimized/////////////////////
int SD_func(SparseMatrix<double> &W, VectorXd &STvec, SparseMatrix<double>   &Wo, int tauR, int tauD)
{
W = W + 1/tauR*(Wo - W); 
for (int k = 0; k < W.outerSize(); ++k)
    for (SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(W, k); it; ++it)
        W.coeffRef(it.row(),it.col()) = it.value() * (1-STvec(it.col())/tauD);

return 1;
}


int main ()
{
SparseMatrix<double> Wo = MatMaker(5000, 5000, 0.1);
SparseMatrix<double> W = MatMaker(5000, 5000, 0.1);
VectorXd STvec = VectorXd::Random(5000);

clock_t tsd1,tsd2;
float Timesd = 0.0;
tsd1 = clock();

///////////////////////////////// Any way to speed up this function???????
SD_func(W, STvec, Wo, 8000, 50);
//////////////////////////////// ??????????

tsd2 = clock();
Timesd += (tsd2 - tsd1);

cout<<"SD time: " << Timesd / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " s" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I have a small script* -- It's a *program*, not a "script".

Comment: There are some simple improvements you can make here without taking advantage of sparsity. If your platform supports it, you can try using `__restrict__` keyword on the arguments of `SD_func()` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/776283/543913)). Also, you can compute the inverse of `tauD` outside the for-loops and multiply by `tauDinv` instead of dividing by `tauD`. Multiplication is much faster than division.

Comment: What are your compiler flags?

Answer (score 3):

The most critical performance improvement (IMO) you can make is to not use `W.coeffRef(it.row(),it.col())`. It performs a binary search in `W` for the element each time. As you are already using `SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(W, k);` it is very simple to change your function to skip the binary search:

```
int SD_func_2(SparseMatrix<double> &W, VectorXd &STvec, SparseMatrix<double>   &Wo, int tauR, int tauD)
{
    W = W + 1/tauR*(Wo - W);
    double tauDInv = 1./tauD;
    for (int k = 0; k < W.outerSize(); ++k)
        for (SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(W, k); it; ++it)
            it.valueRef() *= (1-STvec(it.col())*tauDInv);

    return 1;
}
```

This results in a roughly x3 speedup. Note that I've incorporated @dshin's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262566/how-to-speed-up-a-c-sparse-matrix-manipulation#comment58237332_35262566) that multiplying is faster than division, however the performance improvement is about 90% removing the binary search, 10% multiplication vs. division.