# Avoiding loss of __restrict__ when using GSL spans

Tags: c++, restrict, guideline-support-library

I (mostly) like the new C++ Core Guidelines initiative, and what the Guidelines Support Libary offers. Specifically, I want to use `span`s more. However, I'm coming up against the issue of `__restrict__` not being part of  C++ while I want to/need to use it.

To be more concrete: Without `span`'s, I would declare:

```
void foo(int* __restrict__ p, size_t len);
```

But if I now declare:

```
void foo(gsl::span<int> s);
```

I don't get the `__restrict__` effect unless my compiler super-smart. I could pray real hard to the gods of gcc/clang/msvc and say:

```
void foo(gsl::span<int> __restrict__ s);
```

or alternatively, I could tweak the GSL `span<T>` implementation so that the `T* begin` and `T* end` pointers are themselves `__restrict__`'ed. However,  it's [not at all certain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655853/do-nvcc-gcc-clang-and-msvc-respect-the-restrict-keyword-within-structs?s=1%7C1.3651) this will be respected.

So, can I force the `__restrict__`'ion somehow? Or should I just give it up? This kind of takes the fun out of switching to `span`'s...

Comment: My personal opinion: If you care enough about performance that you want to use `__restrict__` on `gsl::span`you probably don't want to use `gsl::span` in the first place, but first I'd make sure that switching to span actually slows down your program.

Comment: @MikeMB: Why would you say that? It's the exact opposite. We're in C++  ... I want to use a _higher_ level of abstraction _and_ improve performance at the same time... :-)   Also, I want to avoid my API blowing up with ever more parameters.

Comment: @MikeMB: But let me ask you this: How about only using a pointer-and-length pair internally? That is, assigning `int* __restrict__ p = s.data();` ?

Comment: Of course this depends on the particular use case, platform, compiler etc. and my  opinion is based on a pretty small data set. However, my general assumption (until I determined otherwise via benchmarks) is that if you care about the 0-10% performance improvement that `__restrict__` may provide, the overhead introduced by `gsl::span` will probably forbidding. If you care about a particular piece of code, where `__restrict__` allows the compiler to generate significantly more efficient code then it is very likely, that the added indirection will break those compiler optimizations.

Comment: And when I say *"use"* I mean actually using the span to access the data (via iterators or the index operator) - not just having a struct that bundles a pointer and a length, which you then split up again