# How can I accelerate this code (MWE!), e.g. using restrict

Tags: c++, c, optimization, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization

Is there any way I can accelerate this function:

```
void task(int I, int J, int K, int *L, int **ids, double *bar){ 
    double *foo[K];
    for (int k=0;k<K;k++)
        foo[k] = new double[I*L[k]];
        // I am filling these arrays somehow
        // This is not a bottleneck, hence omitted here        
    for (int i=0;i<I;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<J;j++){
            double tmp = 1.;
            for (int k=0;k<K;k++)
                tmp *= foo[k][i*L[k]+ids[j][k]]; //ids[j][k]<L[k]
            bar[i*J+j] = tmp;
        }
}
```

Typical values are: `I = 100,000`, `J = 10,000`, `K=3`, `L=[50,20,60]`.

I read that the `__restrict__` keyword/extension could help, but am not sure how to apply it here. For example, trying to put it into the definition of `foo[k] = new double[...]` I get  `error: '__restrict_ qualifiers cannot be applied to double`. Furthermore, I don't know whether I should / how I could declare `ids` and `ids[j], 1<= j<= J` as restricted.

As a note, in my actual code, I execute as such tasks in parallel in as many threads as my CPU has cores.

I am writing mostly C-compatible C++, so solutions in both languages are welcome.

Comment: `restrict` ain't part of C++, nor is it well defined. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c for details. How about filling in a `std::vector` and returning by value, than you don't even need restrict

Comment: No need of `restrict` here, you don't modify possible aliases.

Comment: Do you *have* to use this ragged/nested array format, instead of a flat 1D array?  There are probably speedups other than `__restrict`, but I'm not sure I understand what this code is doing.  Probably just manually hoisting stuff like `ids[j]` out of the loop will help, and looping over `foo[k][ stuff(k) ]` looks pretty nasty for an inner loop.  Can't you build a more useful data structure in your initial loop, outside the triple-nested loop, that gives you better memory access patterns?

Comment: `double *foo[K];` is not valid C++ as it uses VLA extension.

Comment: _@Bananach_ If you have working code and ask for improvement you should better post that question at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions). Be sure that your question meets the policies setup there.

Comment: Also, you don't show how you tried to put `__restrict` into the declaration of `double *foo[K];`, just some error message.  So this isn't a [mcve] of what you tried.  But it looks like you're saying you tried to put it into an assignment, not a declaration.

Comment: @Jarod42 but `foo` and `bar` could point to the same memory (also, you're right about the VLA, didn't notice that when I boiled down the real code. just assume `K` is global)

Comment: @PeterCordes the nested array format of `foo` is semi-necessary. I could force set all entries of `L` to the largest entry. But I felt that that wouldn't help with the nonlocal access pattern caused by the irregularity of the entries of `ids`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Just in case you were the close voter: Just because the question fits Code Review doesn't mean that it does not fit here, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers a specific programming problem [...] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: I wrote that before I notice that you were doing 2D indexing *inside* each `foo[k][ ... ]`.  Anyway, the reason I couldn't get sane asm from your code is that your inner-most loop does `K++` (incrementing the array bound), not `k++`.  No wonder it was a total mess that didn't actually FP multiply, and that the compiler could never prove any of the integers were non-negative and didn't need sign-extension.

Comment: @Bananach Well, if you're posting here, you should at least provide a [mcve] reproducing your problem (which isn't a strict requirement at SE Code Review). And yes, the close vote is mine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It isn't a strict requirement here either, as per the help center. It is only for debugging questions. The main question here is "how do I accelerate this code". And the code without any `restrict` IS the MCVE from where to start. Well, I guess I should have added a main, and if that's what you find lacking I will be happy to add one.

Comment: Three billion iterations is always going to take a while, and your scattered memory accesses aren't exactly cache-friendly. How long does it take, and how much time are you expecting to save by optimising?

Comment: That array index expression hurts my eyes.  But it does look bad, always be sure to address an array in storage order to maximize the odds that the processor caches are used efficiently.  So k must be incremented in the outer-most loop.  Doing it inner-most is horribly expensive.

Comment: @molbdnilo how long it takes depends on what machine I'm running it on. I hope to save as much as possible. I normally write in python and thus have no idea what I can expect or what I could do to write high perfomance code

Comment: `foo` and `bar` cannot point to the same address, one is local, whereas the other is given in argument...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict claims you can declare an array of `restrict` pointers to double like so in C99/C11:

```
typedef double *array_t[10];
restrict array_t foo;        // the type of a is double *restrict[10]
```

But only gcc accepts that.  I think this is a GCC-ism, not valid ISO C11.  (gcc also accepts
`array_t restrict foo_r;` but no other compilers accept that either.)

ICC warns `"restrict" is not allowed`, clang rejects it with

```
<source>:16:5: error: restrict requires a pointer or reference ('array_t' (aka 'double *[10]') is invalid)
    restrict array_t foo_r;
    ^
```

MSVC rejects it with `error C2219: syntax error: type qualifier must be after '*'`

We get essentially the same behaviour in C++ from these compilers with `__restrict`, which they accept as a C++ extension with the same semantics as C99 `restrict`.

---

**As a workaround, you can instead use a qualified temporary pointer every time you read from `foo`, instead of `f[k][stuff]`.**  I think this promises that the memory you reference through `fk` isn't the same memory you access through any other pointers within the block where `fk` is declared.

```
double *__restrict fk = foo[k];
tmp *= fk[ stuff ];
```

I don't know how to promise the compiler that none of the `f[0..K-1]` pointers alias each other.  I don't think this accomplishes that.

---

**You don't need __restrict here.**

I added `__restrict` to all the pointer declarations, like `int *__restrict *__restrict ids` and it doesn't change the asm at all, according to a diff pane on the Godbolt compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/4YjlDA.  **As we'd expect because type-based aliasing lets the compiler assume that a `double` store into `bar[]` doesn't modify any of the `int *` elements of `int *ids[]`.**  As people said in comments, there's no aliasing here that the compiler can't already sort out.  And in practice it appears that it *does* sort it out, without any extra reloads of pointers.

It also can't alias `*foo[k]`, because we got those pointers with `new` inside this function.  They can't be pointing inside `bar[]`.

(All the major x86 C++ compilers (GCC,clang,ICC,MSVC) support `__restrict` in C++ with the same behaviour as C99 `restrict`: a promise to the compiler that stores through this pointer don't modify objects that are pointed to by another pointer. 
 I'd recommend `__restrict` over `__restrict__`, at least if you mostly want portability across x86 compilers.  I'm not sure about outside of that.)

**It looks like you're saying you tried to put `__restrict__` into an assignment, not a declaration**.  That won't work, it's the pointer variable itself that `__restrict` applies to, not a single assignment to it.

---

The first version of the question had a bug in the inner loop: it had `K++` instead of `k++`, so it was pure undefined behaviour and the compilers got weird.  The asm didn't make any sense (e.g. no FP multiply instruction, even when `foo[]` was a function arg).  This is why it's a good idea to use a name like `klen` instead of `K` for an array dimension.

After fixing that on the Godbolt link, there's still no difference in the asm with / without `__restrict` on everything, but it's a lot more sane.

BTW, making `double *foo[]` a function arg would let us look at the asm for just the main loop.  And you would actually need `__restrict` because a store to `bar[]` could modify an element of `foo[][]`.  This doesn't happen in your function because **the compiler knows that `new` memory isn't pointed-to by any existing pointers**, but it wouldn't know that if `foo` was a function arg.

---

There's a small amount of the work inside the loop is sign-extending 32-bit `int` results before using them as array indices with 64-bit pointers.  This adds a cycle of latency in there somewhere, but not the loop-carried FP multiply dependency chain so it may not matter.  You can get rid of one instruction inside the inner loop on x86-64 by using `size_t k=0;` as the inner-most loop counter.  `L[]` is a 32-bit array, so `i*L[k]` needs to be sign-extended inside the loop.  Zero-extension from 32 to 64-bit happens for free on x86-64, so `i * (unsigned)L[k]` saves a `movsx` instruction in the pointer-chasing dep chain.  Then the inner loop that gcc8.2 makes is all necessary work, required by your nasty data structures / layout.  https://godbolt.org/z/bzVSZ7

I don't know whether that's going to make a difference or not.  I think more likely the memory access pattern causing cache misses will be your bottleneck with real data.

It also can't auto-vectorize because the data isn't contiguous.  You can't get contiguous source data from looping over `j` or `i`, though.  At least `i` would be a simple stride without having to redo `ids[j][k]`.

If you generate `foo[k][...]` and `bar[...]` transposed, so you index with `foo[k][ i + L[k] * ids[j][k] ]`, then you'd have contiguous memory in src and dst so you (or the compiler) could use SIMD multiplies.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the bug. I shouldn't have started editing the code once I pasted it here

Comment: I did try `foo[k] = new __restrict__ double[I*L[k]];`. I get your point that `__restrict` should be part of the declaration instead of the definition, but the question is then: How do I declare an array of pointers, such that each entry has type `double *__restrict`?

Comment: Thanks, I just understood why bar and foo are not in aliasing danger.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that since indexing 64-bit pointers (e.g. `bar`) with 32-bit integers is expensive I should make `i` and `j` 64-bit? Furthermore, if I understnd you correctly, I should use `i*(unsigned)L[k]` instead of `i*L[k]` and `size_t k` instead of `int k`. But isn't `uint64 L` and `uint64_t k` even better?

Comment: @Bananach: oh, declaring a `double *__restrict foo[10];` is an interesting question.  That syntax doesn't work, but it seems there's a way using a typedef that gcc accepts.  https://godbolt.org/z/0JJJSv.  But the other compilers reject it so it's probably a GCC-ism and not valid ISO C11.  I might ask a new question about that, since this question is mostly asking whether `__restrict` would make any difference.  Of course you can work around on any compiler by using `double *__restrict fk = foo[k];` every time you load from the array.

Comment: @Bananach:  Sign-extending `i` and `j` happens once per outer loop, but yeah it might improve code-gen overall in this case.  But no, `uint64_t L[]` wouldn't be any better, and would slightly increase your cache footprint and code size by requiring a REX prefix.  And on Bulldozer-family and Silvermont, 64-bit `imul` is slower than 32-bit `imul` (https://agner.org/optimize/).  With `i` in a register, it's always going to take a separate load instruction to get `i*L[k]` into a register without destroying `i`, so it wouldn't enable `imul r10, qword ptr [rbx + 8*rdi]` instead of `mov`+`imul`.

Comment: Even if x86 was a 3-operand ISA, with `imul dst, src1, src2` instead of `imul dst, src`, writing a 32-bit result to a register zero-extends it for free to 64-bit.  So just using `unsigned` is all that's necessary for that case.  But for loop counters, `unsigned` would be much worse, because unlike signed, `unsigned` overflow is well defined to wrap around, so the compiler can't make as many assumptions based on the program not having undefined behaviour.  It's unfortunately hard to give any kind of general recommendation for using signed vs. unsigned integers.

Comment: I think the wasted instruction in gcc's code-gen that I eliminated with a `size_t` loop counter was actually just a missed optimization.  `k < K` will definitely become false at some point for any possible `K`, so the loop can't be infinite.  Yeah, clang doesn't seem to have that stupid `mov` + `lea` crap, so it's just hand-holding GCC being dumb, not anything fundamental about making the code easier to optimize.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts here, will have to do some reading up about CPU instructions to really understand it though. I hope the important point is that there is no obvious way to get improvements of what I posted

Answer (score 0):

`restrict` does not matter in this case.

Your algorithm is rubbish and does not allow long vector operations to be used (so micro optimizations will not help here at all).

You need to find the way that the elements in the inner loop to occupy the consecutive block of array indexes. As it is done now the compiler has to read the every single element from different positions in the array, it bares the compiler from the loops unrolling and longer vector instructions. It may be also very cache memory unfriendly.

Rethink the algorithm first - premature optimizations will not help if the algorithm is extremely inefficient

## Edit

After the OP comment I just want to show him waht is the difference between "naive" and more efficient (less naive but harder to understand one)

Lets consider the parity of the 32 bit unsigned value. The naive approach:

```
int very_naive_parity(const uint32_t val)
{
    unsigned parity = 0;
    
    for(unsigned bit = 0; bit < 32; bit++)
    {
        if(val & (1U << bit))
        {
            parity = !parity;
        }
    }
    return parity;
}
```

It is very easy to write and understand but it is extremely inefficient. At least 288 instructions will be executed to calculate this parity.

more efficient:

```
int parity(const uint32_t val)
{
    uint32_t tmp = val;
    
    tmp ^= tmp >> 16;
    tmp ^= tmp >> 8;
    tmp ^= tmp >> 4;
    return (0b110100110010110 >> (tmp & 0x0f)) & 1;
}
```

will be executed in 9 instructions (both calculations without function prologues and epilogues)
Is it harder to understand? - definitely yes. But as I wrote efficiency usually means less easy for humans.

Comment: "Your algorithm is rubbish". Without having any suggestions of improving it, that's maybe a bit harsh. Do you know of any way to give the exact same results that `task` gives, for arbitrary inputs of `ids`?

Comment: @Bananach I geve the direction in my answer. You cant write the efficient code having the "naive" inefficient algorithm. As I state  in my answer you need to make arrays organized the way which does not require reads from the non consecutive array elements. It may require rewriting the large parts of your code. When the performance is the important factor you need to have the efficient algorithm

Comment: @Bananach *How can you say the algorithm is rubbish?* - I see it. You need to rethink it. In your case the data has to be organized another way. Will it make code more difficult to write? - Yes but it usually the price of the performance. **But it is your program** and you can write it any way you want. But if ask about the opinion you need to be prepared to hear negative opinions about your work.

Comment: @Bananach: I wonder if sorting `ids` as you construct `foo[]` would be helpful.  Or to somehow factor it out and apply that remapping before or  after the `O(I*J*K)` multiply work, maybe on the way from a temporary array to `bar`.  Although if `K=3` is typical, it's not nearly as bad as a matmul. I have to agree with the harsh assessment here: major restructuring could have huge performance gains, because this code inherently has huge bottlenecks that probably reduce throughput far below even maxing out scalar FP multiply.  Maybe you can take advantage of something we don't know about `ids[]`.

Comment: @ P__J__ I deleted my comment before you wrote that second answer. My point was that if I, say, sorted `ids`, then did computations, and then unsorted, this would only change the *implementation*, so if it accelerated my code, it would be exactly the kind of thing I asked for, and it would not support the view that the *algorithm* is bad but only that the *implementation* is bad. I guess I just misunderstood what you mean by "algorithm". I'm doing this for a scientific computation and in that context, the algorithm behind this is well analyzed and has perfect scaling and complexity etc.

Comment: @Bananach writing efficient code very often requires to sacrify something else. In your case probably you will need much larger tables with repeated data to archive this. You need to see fow your data is organized, how it is accessed and then you need to think how to optimize it having the performance in mind. I am not going to give you the ready solution.

Comment: @Bananach: if any decent amount of your data fits in cache, or if there's any kind of locality anywhere, repeating it might be worse than an extra level of indirection while scattering around in it.  Worth experimenting both ways, but there's going to be a threshold at some point where huge but sequential for maximum brute force isn't actually better than more compact for more cache hits.  Especially if you can get any decent amount of L2 cache hits (typically 256kiB), e.g. from cache-blocking optimizations.  But IDK which side of the threshold your problem might come down on.