# How to optimize Cuda Kernel Performance?

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda

I am building a particle system and face difficulties with the cuda kernel performance that calculates the patricle positions.

```
__global__
void updateParticle(const int num_particles, const double time, const double gravity,
                    GLfloat* device_particleCoordinates, GLfloat* device_particleStartCoordinates,
                    GLfloat* device_particleAcceleration, GLint* device_particleCreatedTime)
{
    int threadId = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (threadId < num_particles)
    {
        int particleLifetime = (time - device_particleCreatedTime[threadId]) / 1000;

        double distanceX = 0.5 * device_particleAcceleration[threadId * 2 + 0] * (particleLifetime * particleLifetime) / 5000.0;
        double distanceY = 0.5 * device_particleAcceleration[threadId * 2 + 1] * (particleLifetime * particleLifetime) / 5000.0;

        device_particleCoordinates[threadId * 2 + 0] = device_particleStartCoordinates[threadId * 2 + 0] + distanceX;
        device_particleCoordinates[threadId * 2 + 1] = device_particleStartCoordinates[threadId * 2 + 1] + distanceY;
    }
}
```

The kernel is called like this:

```
int blockSize = 32;
int nBlocks = maxParticleCount / 32 + 1;
updateParticle << <nBlocks, blockSize >> >(particles.size(), time, gravity, device_particleCoordinates,
                                            device_particleStartCoordinates, device_particleAcceleration, device_particleCreatedTime);

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, particles.size());

HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(particleCoordinatesFlat.data(), device_particleCoordinates, particles.size() * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

*device_particleCoordinates* is linked to an OpenGL buffer so that the coordinates are directly modified.

The performance is not very good and I think it is due to the kernel call. Are there any obvious bugs that might affect performance?

Comment: Why are you using such small blocks?

Comment: @talonmies I tried bigger blocks, but the performance is still the same.

Comment: Use the [nvvp](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-visual-profiler) profiler to find out what is limiting performance.

Comment: @timoschloesser: If that is the case, then it is likely that you are focussing on completely the wrong thing, and the source of poor performance is something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments, this kernel may not be the performance limiter that you think it is.  At least, you've offered no data supporting that idea.  However some suggestions can still be made which should improve the runtime of this kernel.

1. I'm going to assume `GLfloat` is equivalent to `float`.  In that case, especially since the primary output of this kernel (`device_particleCoordinates`) are `float` quantities, its doubtful that any intermediate calculations that are done in `double` precision are providing much benefit.  You could try converting all operations to `float` arithmetic.
2. Division in GPU code can be expensive.  Division by a constant can be replaced by multiplication by the reciprocal of the constant, for floating point operations.
3. Your load and store operations are loading alternate locations. The efficiency can be improved with a vector load/store.  As indicated in the comment, this makes an assumption about alignment of the underlying data.

Here's an example modified kernel (untested) demonstrating these ideas:

```
__global__
void updateParticle1(const int num_particles, const double time, const double gravity,
                    GLfloat* device_particleCoordinates, GLfloat* device_particleStartCoordinates,
                    GLfloat* device_particleAcceleration, GLint* device_particleCreatedTime)
{
    int threadId = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (threadId < num_particles)
    {
        float particleLifetime = (int)((((float)time) - (float)device_particleCreatedTime[threadId]) * (0.001f));
        float2 dpA = *(reinterpret_cast<float2 *>(device_particleAcceleration)+threadId);
        float spl2 = 0.0001f * particleLifetime*particleLifetime;
        float distanceX = dpA.x * spl2;
        float distanceY = dpA.y * spl2;
        float2 dpC = *(reinterpret_cast<float2 *>(device_particleStartCoordinates)+threadId);
        dpC.x += distanceX;
        dpC.y += distanceY;
        *(reinterpret_cast<float2 *>(device_particleCoordinates)+threadId) = dpC;
    }
}
```

According to my testing, these changes will reduce kernel execution time from about 69us (`updateParticle`) to about 54us (`updateParticle1`) for ~1 million particles:

```
$ cat t388.cu
#include <GL/gl.h>
const int ppt = 4;

__global__
void updateParticle(const int num_particles, const double time, const double gravity,
                    GLfloat* device_particleCoordinates, GLfloat* device_particleStartCoordinates,
                    GLfloat* device_particleAcceleration, GLint* device_particleCreatedTime)
{
    int threadId = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (threadId < num_particles)
    {
        int particleLifetime = (time - device_particleCreatedTime[threadId]) / 1000;

        double distanceX = 0.5 * device_particleAcceleration[threadId * 2 + 0] * (particleLifetime * particleLifetime) / 5000.0;
        double distanceY = 0.5 * device_particleAcceleration[threadId * 2 + 1] * (particleLifetime * particleLifetime) / 5000.0;

        device_particleCoordinates[threadId * 2 + 0] = device_particleStartCoordinates[threadId * 2 + 0] + distanceX;
        device_particleCoordinates[threadId * 2 + 1] = device_particleStartCoordinates[threadId * 2 + 1] + distanceY;
    }
}


__global__
void updateParticle1(const int num_particles, const double time, const double gravity,
                    GLfloat* device_particleCoordinates, GLfloat* device_particleStartCoordinates,
                    GLfloat* device_particleAcceleration, GLint* device_particleCreatedTime)
{
    int threadId = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (threadId < num_particles)
    {
        float particleLifetime = (int)((((float)time) - (float)device_particleCreatedTime[threadId]) * (0.001f));
        float2 dpA = *(reinterpret_cast<float2 *>(device_particleAcceleration)+threadId);
        float spl2 = 0.0001f * particleLifetime*particleLifetime;
        float distanceX = dpA.x * spl2;
        float distanceY = dpA.y * spl2;
        float2 dpC = *(reinterpret_cast<float2 *>(device_particleStartCoordinates)+threadId);
        dpC.x += distanceX;
        dpC.y += distanceY;
        *(reinterpret_cast<float2 *>(device_particleCoordinates)+threadId) = dpC;
    }
}

__global__
void updateParticle2(const int num_particles, const double time, const double gravity,
                    GLfloat * __restrict__ device_particleCoordinates, const GLfloat * __restrict__  device_particleStartCoordinates,
                    const GLfloat * __restrict__  device_particleAcceleration, const GLint * __restrict__  device_particleCreatedTime)
{
    int threadId = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (threadId < num_particles)
    {
        float particleLifetime = (int)((((float)time) - (float)device_particleCreatedTime[threadId]) * (0.001f));
        float2 dpA = *(reinterpret_cast<const float2 *>(device_particleAcceleration)+threadId);
        float spl2 = 0.0001f * particleLifetime*particleLifetime;
        float distanceX = dpA.x * spl2;
        float distanceY = dpA.y * spl2;
        float2 dpC = *(reinterpret_cast<const float2 *>(device_particleStartCoordinates)+threadId);
        dpC.x += distanceX;
        dpC.y += distanceY;
        *(reinterpret_cast<float2 *>(device_particleCoordinates)+threadId) = dpC;
    }
}

__global__
void updateParticle3(const int num_particles, const double time, const double gravity,
                    GLfloat * __restrict__ device_particleCoordinates, const GLfloat * __restrict__  device_particleStartCoordinates,
                    const GLfloat * __restrict__  device_particleAcceleration, const GLint * __restrict__  device_particleCreatedTime)
{
    int threadId = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    for (int i = 0; i < ppt; i++)
    {
        float particleLifetime = (int)((((float)time) - (float)device_particleCreatedTime[threadId]) * (0.001f));
        float2 dpA = *(reinterpret_cast<const float2 *>(device_particleAcceleration)+threadId);
        float spl2 = 0.0001f * particleLifetime*particleLifetime;
        float distanceX = dpA.x * spl2;
        float distanceY = dpA.y * spl2;
        float2 dpC = *(reinterpret_cast<const float2 *>(device_particleStartCoordinates)+threadId);
        dpC.x += distanceX;
        dpC.y += distanceY;
        *(reinterpret_cast<float2 *>(device_particleCoordinates)+threadId) = dpC;
        threadId += gridDim.x*blockDim.x;
    }
}

int main(){

  int num_p = 1048576;
  float *dpC, *dpSC, *dpA;
  int *dpCT;
  cudaMalloc(&dpC, num_p*2*sizeof(dpC[0]));
  cudaMalloc(&dpSC, num_p*2*sizeof(dpSC[0]));
  cudaMalloc(&dpA, num_p*2*sizeof(dpA[0]));
  cudaMalloc(&dpCT, num_p*sizeof(dpCT[0]));

  updateParticle<<<(num_p+255)/256, 256>>>(num_p, 1.0, 1.0, dpC, dpSC, dpA, dpCT);
  updateParticle1<<<(num_p+255)/256, 256>>>(num_p, 1.0, 1.0, dpC, dpSC, dpA, dpCT);
  updateParticle2<<<(num_p+255)/256, 256>>>(num_p, 1.0, 1.0, dpC, dpSC, dpA, dpCT);
  updateParticle3<<<num_p/(ppt*256), 256>>>(num_p, 1.0, 1.0, dpC, dpSC, dpA, dpCT);
  updateParticle<<<(num_p+255)/256, 256>>>(num_p, 1.0, 1.0, dpC, dpSC, dpA, dpCT);
  updateParticle1<<<(num_p+255)/256, 256>>>(num_p, 1.0, 1.0, dpC, dpSC, dpA, dpCT);
  updateParticle2<<<(num_p+255)/256, 256>>>(num_p, 1.0, 1.0, dpC, dpSC, dpA, dpCT);
  updateParticle3<<<num_p/(ppt*256), 256>>>(num_p, 1.0, 1.0, dpC, dpSC, dpA, dpCT);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_60 -o t388 t388.cu
$ nvprof ./t388
==32419== NVPROF is profiling process 32419, command: ./t388
==32419== Profiling application: ./t388
==32419== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   30.11%  141.41us         2  70.703us  68.991us  72.416us  updateParticle(int, double, double, float*, float*, float*, int*)
                   23.53%  110.50us         2  55.247us  54.816us  55.679us  updateParticle2(int, double, double, float*, float const *, float const *, int const *)
                   23.31%  109.47us         2  54.735us  54.335us  55.136us  updateParticle3(int, double, double, float*, float const *, float const *, int const *)
                   23.06%  108.29us         2  54.144us  53.952us  54.336us  updateParticle1(int, double, double, float*, float*, float*, int*)
      API calls:   97.56%  291.86ms         4  72.966ms  273.40us  291.01ms  cudaMalloc
                    1.53%  4.5808ms       384  11.929us     313ns  520.98us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.49%  1.4735ms         4  368.37us  226.07us  580.91us  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.22%  670.21us         4  167.55us  89.800us  369.11us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.13%  392.94us         1  392.94us  392.94us  392.94us  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                    0.05%  150.44us         8  18.804us  10.502us  67.034us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.01%  21.862us         4  5.4650us  4.0570us  7.0660us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  10.010us         8  1.2510us     512ns  2.9310us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  6.6950us         3  2.2310us     435ns  3.8940us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  2.3460us         4     586ns     486ns     727ns  cuDeviceGetUuid
$
```

Decorating the pointers with `const ... __restrict__` (`updateParticle2`) doesn't seem to provide any additional benefit for this test case.  Calculating 4 particles per thread (`updateParticle3`) instead of 1 also didn't seem to have a significant impact on the processing time.

Tesla P100, CUDA 10.0, CentOS 7.5

Comment: Please note that use of wider types (`float2` instead of `float`) increases data alignment requirements. It is impossible to know whether these stricter requirements are satisfied in the context of the asker's use case.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Robert Crovella's suggestions, also consider:

- Processing more elements by each kernel thread. You see, setting a thread up to run takes some time - reading parameters, initializing variables (perhaps not so much in your case) etc. Of course - don't process consecutive elements by each thread, but rather have consecutive lanes in a warp process consecutive elements
- Using `__restrict__` on all of your pointer parameters - assuming they point to distinct areas of memory. The `__restrict__` keyword, supported by nvcc, allows the compiler to make various extremely useful optimizations which otherwise it cannot. For more on why `__restrict__` is useful (in C++ generally) see:

  [What does the restrict keyword mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c)