# __restrict vis-a-vis a function optimization behavior of popular compilers

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, clang, restrict

Consider the following function:

```
int bar(const int* __restrict x, void g())
{
    int result = *x;
    g();
    result += *x;
    return result;
}
```

Do we need to read twice from `x` because of the call to `g()`? Or is the `__restrict`ion enough to guarantee the invocation of `g()` does not access/does not alter the value at address `x`?

At [this link](https://godbolt.org/z/gTKSDT) we see the most popular compilers have to say about this (GodBolt; language standard C99, platform AMD64):

- clang 7.0: Restriction respected.
- GCC 8.3: No restriction.
- MSVC 19.16: No restriction.

Is clang rightly optimizing the second read away, or isn't it? I'm asking both for C and C++ here, as the behavior is the same (thanks @PSkocik).

Related information and some notes:

- Readers unfamiliar with `__restrict` (or `__restrict__`) may want to have a look at:  [What does the restrict keyword mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c)
- GCC's [documentation page on restricted pointers](http://%20https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html) in C++.
- I've opened a [bug against GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89479) on this point.
- The fact that `x` is marked `const` is not significant here - we get the same behavior if we drop the `const` and the question stands as is.

Comment: Why not tag it [c]? It is a legit tag for this question (perhaps more legit than the C++ tag) and you'll get more eyeballs.

Comment: @PSkocik: After seeing your GodBolt example - editing accordingly.

Comment: For the optimization across `g()` to be proper, the compiler would have to be certain that it would have noticed any action that could cause the address of `x` to be exposed to the outside world during the execution of `bar`.  In this case there are clearly no such actions, but unless a compiler would be equipped to notice all such actions, it's better to presume that a reference might have leaked when it hasn't than to pretend it can't have leaked in cases where it has.

Comment: @supercat: What you're saying is true if we _don't_ use `restrict`. If we _do_, the compiler doesn't have to be certain of that, it is required to "take my word for it".

Comment: @einpoklum: Function `g()` would be allowed to access the same storage as `*x` if and only if it uses a pointer based upon `x` (and not merely the pointer from which `x` was based) to do so.  A compiler would only be entitled to assume that `g()` could not access `*x` if it could not possibly have legitimately received such a pointer.  In the absence of `__restrict`, a compiler would have to allow for the possibility that the address might have been exposed to outside code before the invocation of `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is effectively a C question, since C is effectively the language that has `restrict`, with a formal spec attached to it.

The part of the C standard that governs the use of `restrict` is [6.7.3.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3.1):

> 1 Let D be a declaration of an ordinary identifier that provides a
>   means of designating an object P as a restrict-qualified pointer to
>   type T.
>
> 2 If D appears inside a block and does not have storage class extern,
>   let B denote the block. If D appears in the list of parameter
>   declarations of a function definition, let B denote the associated
>   block. Otherwise, let B denote the block of main (or the block of
>   whatever function is called at program startup in a freestanding
>   environment).
>
> 3 In what follows, a pointer expression E is said to be based on
>   object P if (at some sequence point in the execution of B prior to the
>   evaluation of E) modifying P to point to a copy of the array object
>   into which it formerly pointed would change the value of E.137) Note
>   that ''based'' is defined only for expressions with pointer types.
>
> 4 During each execution of B, let L be any lvalue that has &L based on
>   P. If L is used to access the value of the object X that it
>   designates, and X is also modified (by any means), then the following
>   requirements apply: T shall not be const-qualified. Every other lvalue
>   used to access the value of X shall also have its address based on P.
>   Every access that modifies X shall be considered also to modify P, for
>   the purposes of this subclause. If P is assigned the value of a
>   pointer expression E that is based on another restricted pointer
>   object P2, associated with block B2, then either the execution of B2
>   shall begin before the execution of B, or the execution of B2 shall
>   end prior to the assignment. If these requirements are not met, then
>   the behavior is undefined.
>
> 5 Here an execution of B means that portion of the execution of the
>   program that would correspond to the lifetime of an object with scalar
>   type and automatic storage duration associated with B.

The way I read it, the execution of `g()` falls under the execution of the `bar`'s block, so `g()` is disallowed from modifying `*x` and `clang` *is* right to optimize out the second load (IOW, if `*x` refers to a non-const global, `g()` must not modify that global).

Comment: @einpoklum Based-on here should mean derived from by means of some (possibly none) pointer arithmetic but without dereferencing. Given `T *restrict P;`,  `P` , `P+2`, `P-42` are all based on `P`. The reason for why the optimization ought to be ok should be mainly in (4.)... Unfortunately, this part of the C standard is written in a super cryptic way, IMO.

Comment: The way clang and gcc process `restrict`, even an expression like `p[1]` won't be regarded as being recognizably based upon `p` in contexts where some pointer not based upon `p` is known to equal `p+1`.