# When is a pointer expression "based on" another pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, restrict-qualifier

In [Section 6.7.3.1 of the C language standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3.1) regarding `restrict`, it says:

> 1. Let D be a declaration of an ordinary identifier that provides a means of designating an object P as a restrict-qualified pointer to type T.
> 2. ...
> 3. In what follows, a pointer expression E is said to be based on object P if (at some sequence point in the execution of B prior to the evaluation of E) modifying P to point to a copy of the array object into which it formerly pointed would change the value of E.

I don't understand what this says - literally:

- Who said P was pointing to a "copy of an array object"?
- Why did P "formerly" point to anything? That is, who says we've changed its value?
- Let's suppose E is a pointer of local scope. Why would modifying *any* pointer expression other than the E pointer itself "change the value of E"? It could change the value pointed to by E maybe. Right?

Can someone help me interpret that piece of text so as to make more sense?

<sub>(Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54875563/1593077))</sub>

Comment: It assumes you're modifying P, that means you've changed its value.

Comment: Footnote 137 at the end of 3 tries to clarify it.

Comment: @Barmar: Modifying P, or modifying the value pointed to by P?

Comment: It says "modifying P to point to a copy". That means modifying P, not the value pointed to by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading several comments, as well as @EricPostpischil's answer, I've tried to synthesize what I believe to be clearer, though a bit longer, wording to clarify things and answer the questions posed.

Original text:

> In what follows, a pointer expression E is said to be based on object P if (at some sequence point in the execution of B prior to the evaluation of E) modifying P to point to a copy of the array object into which it formerly pointed would change the value of E.

Clarified text:

> In what follows, a pointer expression E is said to be based on object P if changing P (with certain restrictions) before E is evaluated would cause E to evaluate to a different value. The restrictions are:
>
> - Trivial sanity restriction: The modification of P must occur at a [sequence point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575350/sequence-points-in-c).
> - P can only be modified to point to an identical copy of what it was pointing to originally. 
>   (And since in general, we can think of pointers always pointing to an array object - P can only be set to point at a copy of that array object).

Answer (score 2):

The definition of "based on" is intended to define a transitive relation among pointers, but its actual wording would yield an unworkable definition which so far as I can tell doesn't match any actual compiler behavior.

It would be simpler to transitively apply the following rule (and this is what compilers seem to do): If `*p` is a pointer of type `T*`, the following pointers are "based on" `p`:

- `p+(intExpr)` or `p-(intExpr)`
- `(otherType*)p`
- `&*p`
- `&p->structMemberofNonArrayType` or `&p->unionMemberofNonArrayType`
- `p->structMemberofArrayType` or `p->unionMemberofArrayType`
- `&p[intExpr]`
- Any pointer based on any of the above

I don't think the Standard is really clear about `(someType*)someIntegerFunction((uintptr_t)p)` and I don't think compiler writers are clear either.

Note that any `q` derived from `p` via any of the above expressions except the one involving casts through `uintptr_t`, the difference between `(char*)p` and `(char*)q` will be independent of the address held by `p`.

Incidentally, here's an example of a problematic corner case:

```
int test1(int * restrict p1, int * restrict p2, int n)
{
    int *restrict p3 = p1+n;
    // How would p4 and p5 be affected if p3 were replaced
    // with a pointer to a copy here?
    int *p4 = p3;
    if (p3 != p1) p4=p1;
    int *p5 = p2 + (p3 == p1);
    *p3 = 1;
    *p5 = 2;
    return *p4;
}
```

Using the transitive ways of forming a pointer based on another, if `n` is zero, `p4` would clearly be based upon `p3`.  Pointer `p5` would not derive from `p3`, however, since there is no sequence of "based upon" steps by which its value could be derived.

Trying to apply the rules given in the Standard to the `n==0` case by replacing `p3` with a pointer to a copy of the array would not affect the value of `p4`, but would affect the value of `p5`.  That would imply that `p4` is not based upon `p3`, but `p5` is, somehow.

I would regard such a result as nonsensical, and I think the authors of the Standard would too, but it follows from the rules given in the Standard, as worded.

Comment: Yes, I know all of that, I've been using restrict for years. But I don't see how the wording says any of this.

Comment: @einpoklum: There are a limited number of actions one can do which would create a pointer with the required traits, and I don't think I've omitted any of them.

Comment: @einpoklum: I suppose I missed a way that a pointer could be "based on" another which my description doesn't cover, but since it would be unworkable and neither gcc nor clang recognizes it, I think my description more accurately describes what compilers actually do.  [BTW, given `int x,y; int restrict *p;`, the value of `p==x ? &x : y` would be affected if `p` were equal to `x` and it were replaced with a copy of its contents.]

Comment: You're not getting what I'm saying. What you've written is just fine (or not, doesn't matter), but it's not an answer to my question about the wording in the standard.

Comment: @einpoklum: The wording in the Standard is inconsistent with the way compilers actually work, and making compilers uphold the Standard-described behavior in all defined cases would needlessly impair many useful optimizations.

Comment: @einpoklum: I think the authors of the Standard knew what they were going for as a concept and tried to describe it in general terms, but recognized that their description would fail in some corner cases.  The "copy of the array" was intended to deal with those corner cases, but fails to fix all of them.  The wording could perhaps have been said that the value of `(char*)p - (char*)e` would be unaffected by the replacement of `p` with a copy, but that's not what it actually says, and I think even that could cause problems with operations that go through `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`.

Comment: Look, you keep talking about things which are simply not an answer to my question.

Comment: @einpoklum: A direct literal answer to your question would be "No.  Nobody can help you interpret what the Committee wrote as a precise rule in a manner that makes more sense than the written text, because the text would be nonsensical if applied for that purpose."  I would think that a description of what the rule was presumably intended to say would be more useful, but if all you want is a direct answer to your direct question, I guess "no" should suffice.

Comment: What about `memcpy`?

Comment: @curiousguy: If `memcpy` is used to copy a pointer, the behavior is analogous to converting a pointer to an integer (or actually sequence of integers) and then later forming a pointer from a sequence of integers.  Any single set of rules would either characterize as UB some constructs that would be useful for some kinds of programs, or forbid some optimizations that would be useful for other types of programs.  For most purposes, having any act which forms pointers from integers treat the pointers thus formed as being based upon any pointers that were converted to integers should be fine...

Comment: ...but the way the Standard is written doesn't say that.

Comment: @curiousguy: A principle that Committee probably thought it too obvious to be worth stating, is that the most practical way of handling `restrict` is to focus on cases where a compiler can prove that an lvalue cannot be based on a pointer.  In particular, a compiler should only assume lvalue L is not based on pointer P if either (1) it understands everything about how `P` is used, or (2) it understands everything about how `L` is derived.  In most cases where `restrict` is useful, at least one of those conditions will apply (often they both will).  Attempts to optimize...

Comment: ...the harder cases will be be more difficult, and generally offer much less benefit, then focusing on the simple cases and treating all pointers whose derivation isn't fully understood as though they may be based upon any pointer whose usage isn't fully understood.  There wasn't any need to have the Standard fully plumb the depths of such cases because analysis of them because implementations would have little reason to care.

Comment: @supercat, I saw your answer only now, after I already posted my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77761618/formal-definition-of-restrict-fails-to-account-for-valid-cases . I agree that the wording of the standard is unworkable, and I give examples that break it in both directions, just as you say. What I am not convinced, however, is if a transitive definition like yours could be workable.

Comment: ... To do an optimization, the compiler has to reason that a certain access is "based on" P, but simultaneously that certain other access is "not based on" P. In the face of undecidable stuff (unknown external functions), the compiler needs to use a weaker-than-perfect effective definition for "based on", and simultaneously a weaker-than-perfect definition for "not based on" (i.e. a stronger-than-perfect definition for "based on"). So it needs two definitions of "based on". I don't see how your suggestion accounts for that.

Comment: @supercat, see also https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2260.pdf for examples involving external functions and an actual compiler bug.

Comment: It might be workable to say something along the lines of: if X was accessed strongly-based on P, and simultaneously accessed by another pointer expression not weakly-based on P, then the behavior is undefined. The most conservative definition then is immediately workable: assume no pointer expr whatsoever is strongly-based on P, and any pointer expr whatsoever is weakly-based on P. No optimizations. Then you conservatively add cases where some exprs can be judged strongly-based on P; you also add cases where some exprs can be judged not weakly-based on P. Keeping the wording self-consistent.

Comment: @log65536: IMHO, the simplest way to define a useful meaning for `restrict` would be to say that if `p` and `q` are pointer expressions, and `p` is "definitely based upon" restrict-qualified `P`, a compiler may treat accesses via `p` and `q` as unsequenced if either (1) the compiler can enumerate all pointers that might be based upon `P`, none of them "leak", and `q` is not among them; or (2) all possible ancestral paths of `q` can be traced back to pointers that existed before `P`, without passing through `P` itself.  Easy rule for both programmers and compilers to analyze, and it allows...

Comment: ...all of the useful optimizations that more complex definitions could accommodate.  It would not, however, be consistent with clang and gcc behaviors, which are designed around the assumption that if two pointers can be shown to hold the same address, they may be treated interchangeably.  Note also, btw, that treating accesses as unsequenced would accommodate the possibility of compilers indicating via predefined macro or other means that they will treat a race condition on a read of some common "single-word" types as yielding a value chosen arbitrarily from among those the object has held...

Comment: ...or will hold, a read of other types that don't have trap representations as yielding an unspecified value; and will treat a race condition involving multiple writes of the same value as equivalent to a single write, and multiple writes that are unsequenced with respect to each other, but sequenced before later some reads, as though they left the object in an unspecified state.  Such guarantees could improve the efficiency with which privileged code can access storage which might also accessible to unprivileged code.  If unprivileged code asks privileged code to output some data, and...

Comment: ...modifies the data in some other thread while the privileged code is running, having the data which is output be unpredictably corrupted may be acceptable, but allowing the other thread to perform privilege escalation attacks should not be.

Answer (score 1):

> Who said P was pointing to a "copy of an array object"?

Pointer arithmetic is defined (in C 2018 6.5.6 8 and 9) in terms of pointers to array elements. For this purpose, a single object is treated as an array of one element. So, whenever we have any non-null object pointer, it is, in this model, pointing into an array.

> Why did P "formerly" point to anything? That is, who says we've changed its value?

The text you quoted is saying “To figure out if `E` is based on `P`, let’s hypothetically make a copy of the array that `P` is pointing into and then assign to `P` a pointer into the corresponding place in the copy.” So the text you quoted is saying we are changing the value of `P`, and then we are comparing the value of `E` with this change and without it.

> Let's suppose E is a pointer of local scope. Why would modifying any pointer expression other than the E pointer itself "change the value of E"? It could change the value pointed to by E maybe. Right?

Objects and values do not have scope. Identifiers have scope. But let’s consider an identifier with block scope:

```
// P is a pointer into A.
// S is the size of A.
// A is the start of an array not contained in any other array.
void foo(char *P, size_t S, char *A)
{
    void *E = P+2;
}
```

For illustration, assume `P` has value 0x1004 and `A` is 0x1000. Is `E` based on `P`?  Well, given the above, `E` is 0x1006. Suppose we consider this code before the definition of `E`:

```
    char *N = malloc(S);
    memcpy(N, A, S);
    P = P - A + N;
```

Suppose `malloc` returns 0x2000. What will the value of `E` be? It will be 0x2006. That is different from 0x1006. Therefore `E` is based on `P`.

On the other hand, consider this:

```
void foo(char **P, size_t S, char **A)
{
    #if OnOrOff
        char *N = malloc(S);
        memcpy(N, A, S);
        P = P - A + N;
    #endif
    char **E = P[3];
}
```

Now, will the value of `E` change depending on whether `OnOrOff` is true or false? No, in either case it will receive the value that is the referenced element of `A`, either directly or from the copy. The fact that `P` might point into `A` or `N` does not affect the value of `E`. So this `E` is not based on `P`.

Comment: I think you hit upon the *intention* of the language in the Standard, but the way the Standard is actually worded is unworkable, resulting in some objects being "based upon" others they have nothing to do with, and in some cases not being based upon pointers from which their values were copied.

Answer (score 0):

Point 3 could be expressed in code as (roughly):

```
#define E(P)  ( (P) + 1 )   // put the expression you want to test here

extern T obj;    // T is some type
T copy = obj;

if ( E(&obj) != E(&copy) )
    printf("the expression in the macro is based on P")
```

The formal language definition used in the standard allows for `E` to be non-deterministic and other pathological cases (e.g. `(P) + rand() % 5`), whereas my example doesn't.

The standard version is that we compare what the result would be of `E(&obj)` with what the result would be of `E(&copy)` in the same context.

Comment: In most cases where `E` is linearly derived from `P`, changing `P` in any fashion would change `E`, and in most cases where it isn't, making `P` point to a copy of the data wouldn't change `E`.  Linear derivation is a transitive property that's easy to recognize, since every pointer value other than a function call, an integer-to-pointer cast, or the result of `?:` will be linearly derived from exactly one other pointer value.  The "formal definition" given in the Standard would coincide with "E is linearly derived from P" except in the hard cases where it's pretty much useless.