# Formal definition of restrict fails to account for valid cases

Tags: c, language-lawyer, restrict-qualifier

The following reasonable program seems to have undefined behavior according to the formal definition of `restirct` in the C standard:

```
void positive_intcpy(int * restrict q, const int * restrict p, size_t n) {
  int *qBgn = q;
  const int *pEnd = p + n;
  // sequence point S
  while (p != pEnd && *p>0) *q++ = *p++;
  if (q != qBgn) fprintf(stderr,"Debug: %d.\n",*(q-1)); // undefined behavior!?
}
int main(void) {
  int a[6] = {4,3,2,1,0,-1};
  int b[3];
  positive_intcpy(b,a,3);
  return 0;
}
```

The function copies integers from one array to another, as long as the integers are positive. The `fprintf` call displays the last positive integer that was copied (if any). There is never any aliasing between `p` and `q`.

Is this really UB, or is my reasoning wrong?

This question concerns section 6.7.3.1 of the C99 standard. The relevant text is unchanged in the [latest draft for C23](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf).

We are talking about the pointer expression `q-1` marked above. Is it *based on the restricted pointer object designated by `p`*?

The standard says:

> In what follows, a pointer expression `E` is said to be *based* on object `P` [where `P` is a restrict-qualified pointer object] if (at some sequence point in the execution of `B` [where `B` is the block associated with the declaration of `P`] prior to the evaluation of `E`) modifying `P` to point to a copy of the array object into which it formerly pointed would change the value of `E` [see footnote]. Note that "based" is defined only for expressions with pointer types.
>
> [footnote] In other words, `E` depends on the value of `P` itself rather than on the value of an object referenced indirectly through `P`. For example, if identifier `p` has type `(int **restrict)`, then the pointer expressions `p` and `p+1` are based on the restricted pointer object designated by `p`, but the pointer expressions `*p` and `p[1]` are not.

In our program, at the sequence point `S` marked above, modifying `p` to point to a copy of the `a` array would cause `p != pEnd` to always be true (because `pEnd` is not modified together with `p`), thus the loop would execute until `*p>0` becomes false, thus the value of `q` at the end of the loop would change (it would be one machine word greater). Therefore we conclude that our expression `q-1` is based on `p`.

Now the standard says:

> During each execution of `B`, let `L` be any lvalue that has `&L` based on `P`. If `L` is used to access the value of the object `X` that it designates, and `X` is also modified (by any means), then the following requirements apply: `T` [where `T` is the type to which `P` is declared to point] shall not be const-qualified. Every other lvalue used to access the value of `X` shall also have its address based on `P`. Every access that modifies `X` shall be considered also to modify `P`, for the purposes of this subclause. If `P` is assigned the value of a pointer expression `E` that is based on another restricted pointer object `P2`, associated with block `B2`, then either the execution of `B2` shall begin before the execution of `B`, or the execution of `B2` shall end prior to the assignment. If these requirements are not met, then the behavior is undefined.

In our case, `L` is `*(q-1)`. `X` is the object at `&b[2]`, which has been modified in `B` to the value of `2`. However, `T` is `const int`, which means the program has UB.

You might say that this is harmless, because the compiler will probably not take advantage of such a hard to prove UB case and so won't mis-optimize it.

But the same logic can be applied in reverse, where it becomes truly dangerous:

```
int f(int *restrict p, int *restrict q) {
  int *p0=p, *q0=q;
  // sequence point S
  if (p != p0) q++;
  if (q != q0) p++;
  *p = 1;
  *q = 2;
  return *p + *q;
}
int main(void) {
  int x;
  printf("%d\n", f(&x,&x));
  return 0;
}
```

GCC does optimize here. `GCC -O0` prints `4`, while `GCC -O3` prints `3`.
Unfortunately, reading the standard literally, GCC must be wrong.

Here's why:

1. In the expression `*q = 2`, `q` is "based on" `p` (because if `p` was modified at sequence point `S` to point to a copy of `x`, the conditional `p != p0` would become true, changing the value of `q`).
2. In the expression `*p = 1`, `p` is "based on" `q` (because if `q` was modified at sequence point `S` to point to a copy of `x`, the conditional `q != q0` would become true, changing the value of `p`).
3. In the body of `f`, any access to any object via a pointer expression is always both "based on" `p` and "based on" `q`. So no restrict-violation, neither of `restrict p`, nor of `restrict q`. Note that no restrict-qualified pointer is ever assigned a pointer expression inside `f` (because `p++` and `q++` do not actually happen).
4. Since there is no `restrict` violation, the program doesn't have UB and the compiler is not allowed to optimize.

It seems to me that the standard failed to define "based on" in the intended way. What is the intended way, then? I mean, clearly there is an intended meaning, which is allowing GCC to optimize, and I believe GCC is morally right in this case. I want to avoid writing programs that might be mis-optimized.

Comment: It seems like this should be a DR to the standardization committee.

Comment: @Barmar Can anybody do that or is there some formal process? I might wait a while to see what other answers and insights are gained here, then collect the evidence and submit a report somewhere. Maybe better to first submit to compiler writers, as we don't want any half-baked "fixes" that might miss corner cases that compiler writers have already thought about. Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 8):

Your assessment that the wording of 6.7.3.1p3 allows for the case you mentioned is correct.  This wording also goes against the intended meaning.

The intent is first mentioned in section 6.7.3p8:

> An object that is accessed through a restrict-qualified pointer has a
> special association with that pointer. This association, defined in
> 6.7.3.1 below, requires that all accesses to that object use, directly or indirectly, the value of that particular pointer.

So by this description `q` and `q-1` are based on the object `q`, not the object `p`.

An example is given in section 6.7.3.1p7:

> EXAMPLE 1 The file scope declarations
>
> ```
> int * restrict a;
> int * restrict b;
> extern int c[];
> ```
>
> assert that if an object is accessed using one of `a`, `b`, or `c`, and that
> object is modified anywhere in the
> program, then it is never accessed using either of the other two

Which further backs up this intent.

By a strict reading of 6.7.3.1p3, the expression `q-1` is based on both the objects `p` and `q`, which doesn't seem to make much sense and is counter to the above quoted description and example.

The intent of 6.7.3.1p3, I believe, was to capture transitive expressions such as the following:

```
int x[5];
int * restrict p = x;
int *p1 = p+2;    // p1 is based on p
int *p2 = p1-1;   // p2 is also based on p
```

As simply stating "an expression including `p` among its operands" wouldn't account for such a case.

A *possible* rewording of 6.7.3.1p3 could be the following:

> A pointer expression **E** is said to be *based on* object **P** if any of the following holds:
>
> - **E** contains **P** as an operand
> - **E** contains an lvalue **V** as an operand, and **V** was set to the value of an expression **E2** which is based on **P**.

Comment: *An object that is accessed through a restrict-qualified pointer has a special association with that pointer*, yes, but that doesn't forbid the object to also have a special association with other restrict-qualified pointers; and in the real world, it often happens. For example, when one function with restrict in the prototype calls another function with restrict in the prototype (or the inlined equivalent of it). I can intuitively understand the intent, but the formal definition is wrong, and I am not able to immediately think of a replacement definition that can fix the problem.

Comment: @log65536 The last part of 6.7.3.1p4 accounts for that example, and in fact 6.7.3.1p11 show exactly that case (with nested scopes as opposed to separate functions) as a valid example.

Comment: @log65536 But yes, the wording of 6.7.3.1p3 needs to be adjusted.

Comment: I think "needs to be adjusted" is an understatement. My intuition is that the real intended definition may be substantially more complicated, requiring introducing of multiple new concepts, so the text as it is is quite far away from a "formal definition". Talking from experience with Coq (a proof assistant often used to formalize semantics of computer programs).

Comment: Regarding your edit: I believe that the standard intends a much more broad meaning for "based on". In the extreme, the function may convert `p` to a `uintptr_t`, send that integer somewhere via email, block the process until it receives a replay, unwrap a valid pointer address from that reply, and assign it to `q`. The intent is that even in then, `q` is "based on" `p`. Black box behavior. So it is perfectly understandable why the spec resorts to a definition-by-hypothetical, and not a direct definition using syntax. It just seems that the hypothetical has problems of its own.

Comment: Because probably not everybody will appreciate the humor, the contrived "assignment by email exchange" example can be read like "assignment inside some unknown external function". Semantics is the same. The external function might be something as trivial as `memcpy`, or as complicated as network access, point is that the compiler (and thus the standard) has to be able to reason without knowledge what is happening inside.

Comment: The email exchange example was also intended to (jokingly) add a philosophical taste to the discussion. If the entity answering the email is a human, does it have free will? How can you say what I would do if I were to be presented with a different address number, instead of the address number I am actually presented? There seems to be a need for better framing of the whole situation, while still allowing for it to be tracked whether information passes from `p` to `q` or not, even in the presence of external black box functions.

Answer (score 0):

I became convinced that the heart of the matter here is that the standard essentially says: **If certain access of X is through an lvalue L1 based on P, and simultaneously certain other access of X is through an lvalue L2 not based on P, the behavior is undefined.**

This places enormous strain on the definition of "based on".

If the definition of "based on" is **too tight** (like in: "based on" shall be only through such and such constructs), L1 would be judged "based on" **less often** while simultaneously L2 would be judged "not based on" **more often**. Such an approximation to the ideal definition is not conservative: it has the potential to UB valid and sensible programs. (Say `int f(int *q, int *restrict p) { h(&p,&q); *p=1,*q=2; return *p+*q; }` and "calling an external function" was not among the constructions that the compiler thought can base `q` on `p`. The compiler could return 3, while the correct answer could be 4. This was [an actual GCC bug](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2260.pdf).)

On the other hand, if the definition of "based on" is **too loose**, L1 would be judged "based on" **more often** while simultaneously L2 would be judged "not based on" **less often**. Such an approximation to the ideal definition is again not conservative: it has the potential to UB valid and sensible programs. (The first example in the question, regarding `fprintf` and `q-1` demonstrates it.)

In such a setting, basically nothing less than an absolutely exact ideal definition of "based on" would suffice in order to keep valid programs from being judged as UB.

I think the spec doesn't succeed in making such an exact definition. In the question, the answers, the comments, and answers to related questions, we have seen problems that arise with the use of conditional expressions, unknown external functions, assignment via known pointer addresses obtained from the environment (`if (p==A) q=A; else if (p==B) q=B; ...`), even some function might block the process, show a core dump to a human and ask him what to assign to `q`... .  A definition based on a hypothetical (what would happen if `p` were to point to a copy of the array object) is hard to justify in many of these cases. I have yet to be convinced that it is even theoretically possible to define the concept of "based on" in a self-consistent way.

Sometimes just part of the information that the address of `p` holds is transferred to `q`. A conditional transfers just one bit of information, repeated conditionals transfer more bits... . Saying either "yes" or "no" in such a case will give either too tight or too loose a definition, and since both directions are not conservative, an ideal definition that cannot be defeated by a contrived example might be impossible.

And practically speaking, compilers can never work with an ideal definition, because of limited reasoning abilities (complete reasoning about Turing-complete programs is theoretically impossible).

So they have to work with conservative approximations. And because neither direction is conservative, they need to work with **two different** approximations. A tight approximation for the L1 case and a loose approximation for the L2 case. That would allow them to judge L1 "based on" P **less often**, while simultaneously judging L2 "not based on" P also **less often**.

As if the standard had said: **If certain access of X is through an lvalue L1 surely-based on P, and simultaneously certain other access of X is through an lvalue X surely-not based on P, the behavior is undefined.**

That would be workable. And I guess that's what compilers actually do.

In the most conservative scenario (-O0) a compiler can assume that no L1 whatsoever is surely-based on P and no L2 whatsoever is surely-not based on P. Thus there is never UB and it will do no optimizations.

A cleverer compiler (-O3) can assume more expressions to be surely-based on P and more expressions to be surely-not based on P. With more reasoning power, increase both of these sets, as long as they stay disjoint, and as long as they stay sensible. A compiler can be morally correct this way, even if it is incorrect by the broken definition of the standard, and even if a self-consistent idealized single definition is not theoretically possible at all.

So maybe the standard should adopt this approach, and define the largest sensible set of expressions that are guaranteed to be "based on", and also the largest sensible set of expressions that are guaranteed to be "not based on". Expressions not participating in either set do not contribute towards UB, because UB is only granted via the vetted sets ("based on" for L1 and "not based on" for L2).

This way, it would be easy for compilers to check that they comply, and it would be easy for programmers to check that their programs won't misbehave.

I post this as an answer in the hope that it could be useful to somebody when reasoning about `restrict`, but I won't mark it as an accepted answer because, well... this is only wishful thinking and not the approach that the standard actually takes. And I have no insider information what approach the compilers actually take.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this really UB, or is my reasoning wrong?

Your reasoning is inconsistent with the intent of the specification.

> In our program, at the sequence point `S` marked above, modifying `p` to point to a copy of the `a` array would cause `p != pEnd` to always be true (because `pEnd` is not modified together with `p`)

But this and the reasoning following from it is not what the spec is trying to describe.  It isn't interested in differences arising from changes in control flow, such as those you present.  It's actually quite hard to describe precisely, so perhaps you can forgive the committee, but here's a go:

- consider an execution of the program, and look at all the expression evaluations that have side effects that affect the value of some evaluation of expression `E`.
- imagine modifying the value of `p` as described, and performing *all those same* evaluations again, taking into account the change in `p`'s value and the differences propagating through the results, but not choosing more, fewer, or different expressions to evaluate, nor performing them in a different order.
- if the ultimate evaluation of `E` yields a different value, then `E` is based on `p`.

That's not perfect, I don't think, but I hope it is adequate for explaining the difference between what the spec means to say and what you present.

In that light, I hope you see that the fact that a change to the value of `p` at some carefully selected place could cause a different sequence of evaluations to be performed is not germane.  In evaluating "based on", we look at effects on the evaluations that *were* performed, not at how that might have changed the sequence of evaluations.

Since `q` and `q - 1` are not, in fact, "based on" `p` in the sense intended by the spec, the program does not violate the requirements related to `restrict`-qualified types.

---

> But the same logic can be applied in reverse, where it

... is irrelevant, because it is wrong in the first place.

But let's look at the program in this example:

> ```
> int f(int *restrict p, int *restrict q) {
>   int *p0=p, *q0=q;
>   // sequence point S
>   if (p != p0) q++;
>   if (q != q0) p++;
>   *p = 1;
>   *q = 2;
>   return *p + *q;
> }
> int main(void) {
>   int x;
>   printf("%d\n", f(&x,&x));
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

`p`, `p0`, `p != p0`, and `p++` are all based on `p`, but not on `q`.

`q`, `q0`, `q != q0`, and `q++` are all based on `q`, but not on `p`.

Either `*p` or `*q` can fill the role of the spec's `L`, with the other performing the `restrict`-violating modification to the one underlying object.  The behavior is therefore undefined, and GCC can do whatever it wants with it.

Comment: Re “It isn't interested in differences arising from changes in control flow, such as you describe”: I expect that was the intent, but it is not what it says. OP is correct and follows the wording of the standard: They propose a situation in which `p` is changed to point to a copy of the array and then explore the consequences of that, which is that control flow changes because `pEnd` does not change. This is a defect in the standard, not incorrect reasoning by OP.

Comment: One fix might be to constrain the hypothetical alteration of the pointer to the starting value of the pointer, instead of at any sequence point. I do not know why the standard allows considering it at any sequence point in the block prior to the expression. Is some purpose served by that?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I don't agree. On the first point, `a` is exactly what `p` was originally pointing to, so changing it to point to a copy of `a` is exactly what the spec says. On the second point, ignoring control flow doesn't fix it, because you can replace `q=p` by something in the spirit of `(p==X ? q=X : p==Y ? q=Y : p==Z ? q=Z : ...)`, for some number of known pointers X,Y,Z,..., which you can craft just so as to cause trouble). Then if you ignore control flow, you'd say `q` is not based on `p`, while in reality `q` is based on `p`, even if the assignment is performed in a contrived way.

Comment: @EricPostpishcil: Constraining the sequence point doesn't work, either, because you could do it like this: `{ int a[5]; { int *restrict p=a; /* only possible sequence point */ if (p != a) ... } }`.

Comment: You're right on the first point, @log65536.  I have removed those comments, which were wholly separable from the rest of the answer.  On the second point (1) I explicitly note that my explanation is not perfect, however (2) ternary expressions are expressions, not control flow.  If you like, imagine that I said "full expression" instead of merely "expression" in the first bullet point.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I have modified the wording to "inconsistent with the intent of the specification", with a few other, smaller modifications to similar effect.  As for the starting value *vs* the value at any sequence point, I suspect that the reason the latter was chosen is that `restrict` is a type qualifier, and so applies to *every* value that an object of a `restrict`-qualified type takes.  From that perspective, perhaps the required correction involves defining the semantics in terms of pointer values instead of pointer objects.  Not that that wouldn't have its own problems.