# Do C compilers follow the "formal definition of `restrict`"?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, c99, restrict-qualifier

Consider this code:

```c
extern int A[2];

/* Just returns `p` back. */
extern int *identity(int *p);

int f(int *restrict p)
{
    int *q = identity(p);  /* `q` becomes "based on" `p` */
    int *r = A + (p == q);
    *p = 1;
    *r = 2;
    return *p;
}
```

Is `r` "based on" `p` here? According to the standard, it seems like it must be. In particular:

> [...] a pointer expression E is said to be based on object P if (at some sequence point in the execution of B prior to the evaluation of E) modifying P to point to a copy of the array object into which it formerly pointed would change the value of E.

Where `P` is:

> a restrict-qualified pointer to type T.

Given the above definition, `r` *is* based on `p`, since "modifying `p` would change the value of `A + (p == q)`" (hence `r`'s). *Even though* `r` will definitely point inside the `A` array, it still must be based on `p`, counter-intuitively. Perhaps this is where I'm wrong.

GCC and Clang do *not* think the above is true. They optimize the last load on `p` to just `return 1;`. So, `f(&A[1])` would incorrectly return `1`, instead of `2`.

Are the implementors misinterpreting the standard? If not, then `f(&A[1])` is undefined behavior, but *why* so, what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876050/when-is-a-pointer-expression-based-on-another-pointer

Comment: `restrict` is what enables this optimization. When you declare `p` to be restricted, it means you promise not to modify its target through some other pointer. When you assign to `*r` you're violating this promise and causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @Barmar, Re "*you're violating this promise*",  Only if `p` is a pointer to `A` or within `A`.

Comment: @Barmar AFAIK this is not how `restrict` works. You can alias a `restrict`-qualified pointer _and_ modify the object it designates to, as long as the lvalue aliasing it, is "based on" on the restricted pointer. Hence why I'm basically asking what does qualify as "based on". So I don't see _any_ UB in this code, that's why I believe the compilers are not allowed to optimize here. If you disagree, can you point where the standard explicitly says this is UB?

Comment: @pan it is some kind of promise.

Comment: I think a conclusion that has been reached in other questions about `restrict` is the authors of the standard tried to come up with a formal definition, but it does not really work. That is, it is not a correct definition for what we want `restrict` to mean. Nonetheless, I think you are correct here, the compilers are not correctly determining that `q` and `r` are based on `p` according to the formal definition.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's interesting, thanks. I guess the answer to my question is "the compilers don't follow the standard and the standard is buggy".

Comment: This has been asked many times before. "The formal definition of restrict" is not a helpful part of the standard. If a language feature needs that amount of formality and complexity (restrict does not), then that feature ought to be broken by design since it was made much too complex. Someone in the ISO C WG had too much spare time at some point and the rest of them didn't object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal definition of `restrict` is problematic.  The wording conveys the spirit of the idea moderately well, but if you take it as the formal definition it claims to be then it doesn't really serve (what I take to be) the intended purpose.

> Is `r` "based on" `p` here?

Yes, according to the formal definition, provided that `identity(p)` returns the value of `p`, as its name suggests.  You already quoted the relevant text.
In that case, modifying `p` after the initializer for `q` is evaluated and before the initializer for `r` is evaluated would change the value of `r`.

Remember, though, that `restrict` is about aliasing, and "based on" is about determining which expressions must be considered as possible aliases of each other, so as to not have to account for possible aliasing of `restrict`-qualified pointers with expressions *not* based on them.  The spec does not exclude "based on" status attaching via the equality comparison in your example, but that should be considered a flaw in the spec.

> GCC and Clang do *not* think the above is true. They optimize the last load on `p` to just `return 1;`. So, `f(&A[1])` would incorrectly return `1`, instead of `2`.
>
> Are the implementors misinterpreting the standard?

Yes and no.  They are implementing what I take to be the *intent* of the standard, which is that `restrict` implies that they can assume that `p` does not alias any members of `A`.

But they are not implementing the *letter* of the spec:

> let `L` be any lvalue that has `&L` based on `P`. If `L` is used to access the
> value of the object `X` that it designates, and `X` is also modified (by any means), then the following
> requirements apply: [...] Every other lvalue used to access the value of
> `X` shall also have its address based on `P`. Every access that modifies `X` shall be considered also to
> modify `P`, for the purposes of this subclause.

(C17 6.7.3.1/4)

If we accept, per the actual wording of the spec, that `r` is based on `p`, then the implementation is obliged to act as if the assignment to `*r` modifies `p`, which is to say that it cannot assume that `*p` evaluates to the same value after the assignment to `*r` that it did before.

> If not, then `f(&A[1])` is undefined behavior, but why so, what am I missing?

I'm confident that `f(&A[1])` is *intended* to have undefined behavior, because it is intended that `r` should not be based on `p` in your example.  If indeed it were not, then the assignment to `*r` would violate "Every other lvalue used to access the value of `X` shall also have its address based on `P`."

Comment: So, `f(&A[1])` is _intended_, as you say, to be UB, _but_ taking the "formal definition" as currently written, it kind-of isn't. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, @pan, if we go by the spec as actually written, the behavior of `f(&A[1])` is defined.