# How to specify a pointer as a "thread_local" storage in C++?

Tags: c++, thread-local

I am currently working on optimizing a piece of code of math operations, where it loops over a pointer storage and saves the result inplace.
I noticed that at every assignment the compiler emit an memory-store instruction, like this (the `vmovaps` to be noticed):

```
        114 [1]                         top_data_c[pc] += w1 * bottom_data_hwc[o1 + pc];
0x55555558bf70  <+ 2624>        c4 c1 78 10 0c 02                 vmovups (%r10,%rax,1),%xmm1
0x55555558bf76  <+ 2630>        48 83 c1 01                       add    $0x1,%rcx
0x55555558bf7a  <+ 2634>        c4 c3 75 18 4c 02 10 01           vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%r10,%rax,1),%ymm1,%ymm1
0x55555558bf82  <+ 2642>        c4 c2 25 a8 0c 04                 vfmadd213ps (%r12,%rax,1),%ymm11,%ymm1
0x55555558bf88  <+ 2648>        c4 c1 7c 29 0c 04                 vmovaps %ymm1,(%r12,%rax,1)
        115 [1]                         top_data_c[pc] += w2 * bottom_data_hwc[o2 + pc];
0x55555558bf8e  <+ 2654>        c4 c1 78 10 04 01                 vmovups (%r9,%rax,1),%xmm0
0x55555558bf94  <+ 2660>        c4 c3 7d 18 44 01 10 01           vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%r9,%rax,1),%ymm0,%ymm0
0x55555558bf9c  <+ 2668>        c4 c2 7d b8 ca                    vfmadd231ps %ymm10,%ymm0,%ymm1
0x55555558bfa1  <+ 2673>        c4 c1 7c 29 0c 04                 vmovaps %ymm1,(%r12,%rax,1)
        116 [1]                         top_data_c[pc] += w3 * bottom_data_hwc[o3 + pc];
0x55555558bfa7  <+ 2679>        c4 c1 78 10 04 00                 vmovups (%r8,%rax,1),%xmm0
0x55555558bfad  <+ 2685>        c4 c3 7d 18 44 00 10 01           vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%r8,%rax,1),%ymm0,%ymm0
0x55555558bfb5  <+ 2693>        c4 c2 75 98 c1                    vfmadd132ps %ymm9,%ymm1,%ymm0
0x55555558bfba  <+ 2698>        c4 c1 7c 29 04 04                 vmovaps %ymm0,(%r12,%rax,1)
        117 [1]                         top_data_c[pc] += w4 * bottom_data_hwc[o4 + pc];
0x55555558bfc0  <+ 2704>        c5 f8 10 0c 07                    vmovups (%rdi,%rax,1),%xmm1
0x55555558bfc5  <+ 2709>        c4 e3 75 18 4c 07 10 01           vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%rdi,%rax,1),%ymm1,%ymm1
0x55555558bfcd  <+ 2717>        c4 c2 75 b8 c0                    vfmadd231ps %ymm8,%ymm1,%ymm0
0x55555558bfd2  <+ 2722>        c4 c1 7c 29 04 04                 vmovaps %ymm0,(%r12,%rax,1)
0x55555558bfd8  <+ 2728>        48 83 c0 20                       add    $0x20,%rax
0x55555558bfdc  <+ 2732>        48 39 4d c0                       cmp    %rcx,-0x40(%rbp)
0x55555558bfe0  <+ 2736>        77 8e                             ja     0x55555558bf70
```

however, when I changed the pointer into a local "stack array" variable, i.e. `T top_data_c[1024]`, the store instruction appears only at end of the loop:

```
        114 [1]                         top_data_c[pc] += w1 * bottom_data_hwc[o1 + pc];
0x55555558bbe0  <+ 1712>        c5 f8 10 0c 03                    vmovups (%rbx,%rax,1),%xmm1
0x55555558bbe5  <+ 1717>        48 83 c1 01                       add    $0x1,%rcx
0x55555558bbe9  <+ 1721>        c4 e3 75 18 4c 03 10 01           vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%rbx,%rax,1),%ymm1,%ymm1
0x55555558bbf1  <+ 1729>        c4 c2 25 a8 0c 04                 vfmadd213ps (%r12,%rax,1),%ymm11,%ymm1
0x55555558bbf7  <+ 1735>        c5 fc 28 c1                       vmovaps %ymm1,%ymm0
        115 [1]                         top_data_c[pc] += w2 * bottom_data_hwc[o2 + pc];
0x55555558bbfb  <+ 1739>        c4 c1 78 10 0c 03                 vmovups (%r11,%rax,1),%xmm1
0x55555558bc01  <+ 1745>        c4 c3 75 18 4c 03 10 01           vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%r11,%rax,1),%ymm1,%ymm1
0x55555558bc09  <+ 1753>        c4 c2 7d 98 ca                    vfmadd132ps %ymm10,%ymm0,%ymm1
        116 [1]                         top_data_c[pc] += w3 * bottom_data_hwc[o3 + pc];
0x55555558bc0e  <+ 1758>        c4 c1 78 10 04 02                 vmovups (%r10,%rax,1),%xmm0
0x55555558bc14  <+ 1764>        c4 c3 7d 18 44 02 10 01           vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%r10,%rax,1),%ymm0,%ymm0
0x55555558bc1c  <+ 1772>        c4 e2 35 b8 c8                    vfmadd231ps %ymm0,%ymm9,%ymm1
        117 [1]                         top_data_c[pc] += w4 * bottom_data_hwc[o4 + pc];
0x55555558bc21  <+ 1777>        c4 c1 78 10 04 01                 vmovups (%r9,%rax,1),%xmm0
0x55555558bc27  <+ 1783>        c4 c3 7d 18 44 01 10 01           vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%r9,%rax,1),%ymm0,%ymm0
0x55555558bc2f  <+ 1791>        c4 c2 75 98 c0                    vfmadd132ps %ymm8,%ymm1,%ymm0
0x55555558bc34  <+ 1796>        c4 c1 7c 29 04 04                 vmovaps %ymm0,(%r12,%rax,1)
0x55555558bc3a  <+ 1802>        48 83 c0 20                       add    $0x20,%rax
0x55555558bc3e  <+ 1806>        48 3b 8d c8 fb ff ff              cmp    -0x438(%rbp),%rcx
0x55555558bc45  <+ 1813>        72 99                             jb     0x55555558bbe0
```

it comes up that the compiler keeps the pointer store action away from optimization due to its thread unsafeness.

Declaring stack array or temporary variable copying from and back looks so dirty in such implementation, is there any way to make such pointer storage thread-safe to compiler's sense? Of course such computation is totally thread-safe (it works quite similar to GPU).

Answer (score 4):

Unless you for some reason declared the `top_data_c` pointer as `volatile`, the compiler is free to assume that no outside (including concurrent) modifications happen to the data it writes, so the lack of optimization is not to blame on threading (and not solved by thread local semantics).

The real problem here is aliasing - the compiler *cannot* assume that `top_data_c[pc]` isn't somewhere inside `bottom_data_hwc` (it could be the same as `bottom_data_hwc[o4 + pc]`, who knows?), so it has to do the stores. What alleviates this issue in the "stack array" case is (if I'm not mistaken) the fact that `top_data_c` is an array instead of a pointer (not that it is on the stack or that it's thread-local).

Short excursion into strict aliasing rules: The compiler can assume that pointers to incompatible types (e.g. `int` and `double`) cannot point to the same location. If you are inside `void foo(int* x, double* y)` then, under strict aliasing rules, writing to `x` cannot change what you read from `y` (and vice versa), so the compiler is free to reorder or elide stores and reads to/from `x` and `y` within this function as it wants.

But inside `void foo(double* x, double* y)`, this guarantee vanishes. If `x == y` (or `x == y + n`) then writes and reads to `x` and `y` can potentially interact with each other, and the compiler has no choice but to carry out each load/store.

You should look into the `restrict`-related keywords, which signal to the compiler "accesses to `x` happen *only* through `x` (and its copies) in this function". Some material:

[What does the restrict keyword mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c)

https://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html

http://assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/load-hit-stores-and-the-__restrict-keyword/

Comment: Cool! Thanks Max! I added **restrict** and it works as my expectation!

Comment: Another question, how does **restrict** work on const pointer? Why it is `memcpy (void *__restrict __dest, const void *__restrict __src)` but not `memcpy (void *__restrict __dest, const void *src)` ?

Comment: `const void*` means you can't write to the pointed location, so `restrict` effectively only excludes read aliasing (because you can't write), other than that the `const` has no interaction with `restrict`... But there is also no particular benefit from restricting both vs restricting one, as long as those two are the only pointers dereferenced within the function: https://godbolt.org/z/VuSQFu. But putting `restrict` on both arguments makes the point clear to the user and allows implementations to deref global pointer variables without aliasing causing performance problems.