# Const and non-const pointer to the same region

Tags: c++

I'm writing the folowing function:

```
void SPI_TransmitReceive(const uint8_t* txbuf, uint8_t* rxbuf, size_t size);
```

And calling it with the same buf for tx and rx:

```
uint8_t mybuf[200];
SPI_TransmitReceive(mybuf, mybuf, 200);
```

Will there be an undefined behavior?

UPD:
To clarify the question.
Assume that:

```
void SPI_TransmitReceive(const uint8_t* txbuf, uint8_t* rxbuf, size_t size) {
    std::memmove(rxbuf, srcbuf, size);
}
```

cppreference says that memmove may lead to UB if regions are overlapping. Is it a typo?

Comment: That is up to the specification of that function. What does its documentation say? (My feeling is that it is unlikely to support that.)

Comment: How can we possibly know that without seeing that function's body/implementation/documentation?

Comment: If you actually mean that you are writing the function yourself, then obviously it depends on what you do with these pointers in the function...

Comment: It is *legal* to call that function with `mybuf` as you wrote it. Whether or not it breaks things is up to the implementation of `SPI_TransmitReceive`

Comment: This is no different than having `int x = 0;` then `int& y = x;` and `const int& z = x;` you can have multiple references to the same object, that differ by `const`

Comment: Might be of interest [What does the restrict keyword mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c)

Comment: No.  There is no Undefined Behavior in the code shown here.  The compiler is aware that your two pointers may point to the same data.

Comment: `memmove` is specifically designed for the overlapping cases, where `memcpy` fails.  It's literally the only difference between `memmove` and `memcpy`.  Now, completely overlapping is unusual (normally there's a partial overlap, to shift data up or down in a buffer), but can happen when the immediate caller doesn't know the pointers are equal.  If worried, you might protect the memmove call with `if (txbuf != rxbuf)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, they'll point to the same place. If the code in `SPI_TransmitReceive` does `rxbuf[2] = 3`, then following that call, it'll see that `txbuf[2] == 3`. Some functions may not be expecting that situation; you'd need to check the documentation (or the source code) to see whether it screws things up. But from a language perspective the behavior is still well-defined.