# When to use restrict and when not to

Tags: c, pointers, c99, restrict-qualifier

I have a general understanding of `restrict` but I'm hoping to clarify some fine points.  I have a function that reads a null-terminated string from one buffer and writes out a URL encoded version in another buffer.  The function has this signature (currently without `restrict`):

```
char const *StringUrlEncode(char const *unencoded, 
                            char *encoded,
                            char *encodedEnd);
```

`unencoded` is my null-terminated source string.  The destination buffer is represented by `encoded` and `encodedEnd`, where `encoded` points to the first `char` in the buffer and `encodedEnd` points to the first char *after* the buffer, i.e. the function will write `char`s up to but *not including* the location pointed to by `encodedEnd` -- this is your basic `begin`/`end` iterator pair if you're familiar with C++ STL conventions.

If I add `restrict` to this function, should it only be applied to the first two parameters:

```
char const *StringUrlEncode(char const *restrict unencoded, 
                            char *restrict encoded,
                            char *encodedEnd);
```

or is there some benefit I'm not understanding by adding it to all three parameters?

I can see that making the input and output buffers `restrict` helps the compiler know that they don't overlap.  But since the last parameter, `encodedEnd`, is only used to mark the end of the output buffer, I'm thinking that `restrict` wouldn't really be any help to the compiler here (though I assume it wouldn't hurt, other than adding unnecessary noise to the function declaration).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try Mike Acton's article [here](https://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html) ([old link](http://www.cellperformance.com/mike_acton/2006/05/demystifying_the_restrict_keyw.html)).  Restrict is frightening because of both the performance implications of not using it and the consequences of using it incorrectly.

In your case, it sounds like you could safely apply restrict to all three pointers as none alias the same memory area.  However there is going to be little to no performance benefit from using it on the third pointer.

Comment: I've read Mike's article (twice now) and it's a good start, but left me with some questions :-)

Comment: The link given is non-functional.  Google suggests there's an updated version at http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html (validated 2009-09-06) but that is giving problems too.  The cached version is available at Google.

Answer (score 7):

In this particular case it won't make a difference whether **encodedEnd** is restrict or not; you have promised the compiler that no one aliases **unencoded** and **encoded**, and so the reads and writes won't interfere with each other.

The real reason that restrict is important in this case is that without it the compiler can't know that writes through **encoded** won't affect reads through **unencoded**. For example, if

```
encoded == unencoded+1
```

then each write to **encoded** would affect each subsequent read from **unencoded**, so the compiler can't schedule the load until the write has completed. restrict promises the compiler that the two pointers don't affect the same memory, so it can schedule loads far enough ahead to avoid pipeline stalls.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're right that it wouldn't hurt.  Your loop pointer (call it p) will equal encodedEnd at the end of the loop.  But nothing need be accessed after the loop (from either p or encodedEnd), so that shouldn't be a problem.  I don't think it will help, either, because nothing is ever written or read from encodedEnd so there's nothing to optimize away.

But I agree with you having the first two restrict should really help.

Comment: Note that dereferencing encodedEnd is undefined behavior since encoded is also restrict - so indeed, it doesn't matter at all whether encodedEnd is restrict or not.