# Using restrict pointers within structure in C

Tags: c, restrict-qualifier

I am trying to understand the effect of using restrict keyword over arrays defined inside the same struct. When I compare the assembly code for cases with and without restrict pointer, I see no difference. My code "**test_res.c**" is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int index;
    int index2;
    double *restrict a;
    double *restrict b;
    double *restrict c;
} matstruct;

void finalVal (matstruct *m)
{
    int i,j;
    for (j=0; j<m->index2; j++){
        for (i= 0; i<m->index; i++){
            m->b[i] = sqrt(m->a[i]) * sqrt(m->b[i]);
            m->c[i] = sqrt(m->a[i]) + sqrt(m->b[i]); 
            m->c[i] += sqrt(m->a[i]) * sqrt(m->b[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    matstruct *m = malloc (sizeof(matstruct));
    m->index = 100000;
    m->index2 = 10000;
    m->a = malloc (sizeof(double)*(m->index));
    m->b = malloc (sizeof(double)*(m->index));
    m->c = malloc (sizeof(double)*(m->index));
    for (int i=0; i<m->index; i++){
        m->a[i] = 10.0+i;
        m->b[i] = 20.0+i;
        m->c[i] = 30.0+i;
    }
    finalVal (m);
    free (m->a);
    free (m->b);
    free (m->c);
    free (m);
    return 0;
}
```

I use the following steps to get assembly code:

1. gcc -g -O3 -c test_res.c
2. objdump -S test_res.o > test_res.s

Now, remove the "restrict" keyword from the code and create another assembly code "test_no_res.s" using above steps.
Finally, compare the two assembly codes. There seems no difference.

So, does it mean that using the "restrict" keyword inside the structure has no effect ?

Comment: `restrict` enables some optimizations. Sometimes there's nothing to be optimized, so it has no effect.

Comment: When you examine the assembly code of the version with `restrict`, do you see any opportunities for optimization that are not performed?

Comment: @Barmar. I haven't analysed the assembly code. I am just trying to understand whether restrict actually works or compiler is smart enough to do anti-aliasing without it.

Comment: I don't see how it could do that, since there's nothing preventing the pointers from being aliases.

Comment: If you declared the function `static`, the compiler could theoretically determine that the pointers have no overlap in the caller. But since it could be called from another compilation unit, it can't do that optimization.

Comment: Can we have some different function with these arrays and struct, such that the effect of restrict is clearly evident ? 
Any function is ok but its input parameter must be the struct "m" only.

Comment: Your question seems very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005473/rules-for-using-the-restrict-keyword-in-c). Does it answer your question?

Comment: See the example on [cppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict), run it in your machine and compiler and see what happens. . . At the example there are arguments and example of generated code...

Comment: @Barmar Given the currently-posted code could all be replaced under the as-if rule by `int main(void){ return 0; }`, I wouldn't trust any difference in the optimized and unoptimized output from the compiler to be indicative of what would happen for more complex code that actually uses the data and outputs results.

Comment: @AndrewHenle And even if you added code to print it, since all the data comes from static initialization, the compiler could execute it all at compile time. It needs to get dynamic input and produce output to avoid over-optimization.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's sufficient to verify that the function actually gets called from main() in the disassembly. Because if so (and it wasn't inlined), then the function has to be generated as "stand-alone" -the compiler cannot assume that the function won't get also called from a different translation unit.

Comment: Are the arrays m->a, m->b and m->c, behaving like restrict pointers inside "void finalVal (matstruct *m)" or they got changed to simple non-restrict pointers inside the function. I mean to ask whether these pointers remain restrict pointers when they are passed via structures to functions? Or should I explicitly send each restrict pointer as an argument to the function ?

Answer (score 0):

`restrict` only matters in case of "pointer aliasing" optimizations. That is, cases where the compiler cannot be sure if two pointers pointing at something outside the current function or translation unit point at the same memory location or not. In case there is a risk of them doing so, the compiler might have to make additional copies of the pointed-at data etc.

`restrict` is a contract between the programmer and the compiler, where the programmer swears "I promise that the data pointed at is only ever accessed through this very pointer, and it is not pointing at some global variable either".

In your code, it doesn't really matter where the individual pointers a,b,c point. The compiler just needs to grab whatever they point at, copy it and pass it to `sqrt`. So there's no obvious reason why `restrict` would matter here.

Giving an example where `restrict` matters based on your code proved hard, neither gcc nor clang seem smart enough to take advantage of it in this specific case. Better examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75854539/584518

Comment: So can we say that functions "void finalVal (matStruct *m)" and "void finalVal (matstruct *m, double *restrict a, double *restrict b, double *restrict c)" are equivalent in terms of compiler optimization ? Here a, b, c are m->a, m->b, m->c arrays.