# C++ const-correctness and const members

Tags: c++, constants, compiler-optimization, const-correctness, construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does const-correctness give the compiler more room for optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313730/does-const-correctness-give-the-compiler-more-room-for-optimization)

During the last few weeks, I have developed a thing for making all my non-static members `const` if possible in order to avoid unintended programming errors. However, this practice provides some enormous drawbacks, especially for entity objects, since e.g. no one will ever be able to call an assignment operator anymore, should they chose to aggregate such an entity object directly rather than using a pointer.

My question is as to whether this `const` member philosophy even provides any compiler optimization bonuses.

```
class User {
public:
    User(const std::string &, const std::vector<unsigned char> &);
    ~User();
    const std::string &getName() const;
    const std::vector<unsigned char> &getPasswordHash() const;
private:
    std::string name;
    std::vector<unsigned char> passwordHash;
};
```

Would it provide my compiler with any significant optimization possibilities if this `class`' members were `const`? Given the fact that other classes usually would usually aggregate non-const `User` objects, but almost all my algorithms would accept a `const User &`?

So do the `const` members provide any significant optimization opportunities over the already present `const User &` mentality? And would it justify using `const User *` aggregations and reconstruct the objects on change rather than using the assignment operator?

Thanks for some quick remarks!

Comment: Duplicate. Please keep in mind that you are not using const to go faster, but to reduce bug opportunities in your program by declaring intente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out about it at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313818/1155650) and also [HERE](http://parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html.)

Comment: My bad, sorry. Answers the question perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

First, a note on vocabulary: entity objects, by definition, have
identity, and so don't support assignment.  I think what you mean is
value objects.

Otherwise: I've generally found very little advantage in making data
members const.  As you've noticed, doing so makes assignment impossible,
which means that they can't be const for value types.  For entity
objects, which can't be assigned, there is some value in making
immutable members (e.g. an identifier) const, but as all accesses are in 
a small block of code which you control, the value is considerable less
than it is for `const` in the public interface.

Another possibility is to define immutable types for such members.  It's
far more expressive to define `name` as an `Identifier` than it is to
define it as an `std::string`, and `Identifier`, even if it contained
only a single data member with type `std::string` would limit what you
could do with it.  (It would also facilitate changing the representation
of the identifier later.)