# How does const pointer arguments optimized when calling functions?

Tags: c, pointers, arguments, compiler-optimization

How does compilers optimizes theese 4 types of function definitions. Is there any optimization done in sense of argument passing?

```
int check_collision(const SDL_Rect const *A,const SDL_Rect const *B) { ... }

int check_collision(SDL_Rect const *A,SDL_Rect const *B) { ... }

int check_collision(const SDL_Rect *A, SDL_Rect const *B) { ... }

int check_collision(SDL_Rect *A, SDL_Rect *B) { ... }
```

And if it matters, what do you think would be the preferable way of passing read only arguments to a function in cases where these argument might inefficent to copy when calling the funcion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does const-correctness give the compiler more room for optimization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313730/does-const-correctness-give-the-compiler-more-room-for-optimization)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `const` in any of these cases to indicate the purpose of your usage more clearly and writing more readable code, modern day compilers are efficient and smart enough to apply required optimization's whether you pass the function argument as `const` or not.

In short, use `const` in this case for readability & preventing usage errors, & not for compiler optimization,
Compiler is smart enough to take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your first three declarations are effectively all the same, even if SDL_Rect is a typedef (because the const keyword never "penetrates" a typedef, as I like to put it).

The const keyword acts in different ways in different places.  In this case it merely makes a (revocable) promise that check_collision will not alter or replace *A (nor A[i] for any i), nor *B (nor B[j] for any j).  However, it's possible that A[i] and/or B[i] are modified by any function that your code calls, because the underlying objects may be modifiable and some other function might know how to access them.  The C99 keyword "restrict" tells the compiler that this is not the case, and provides a lot of opportunities to optimize; it's usually what you want here.

C99 also adds a new use for the "static" keyword to enable certain compile-time optimizations that go above and beyond those provided by "restrict".  These apply only when the pointers point to the first element of arrays whose size is at least some knowable value.  (It's meant for vectorization, mainly.)

As @Als noted, it's best to start with the simplest statement of "what you mean" and only add optimization keywords if you discover that the program is taking a lot of time in some particular part(s) of the program.