# PHP: REST versus Functions

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

Ok, this is probably something answered millions of times, but I couldn't find an answer on Google (maybe I'm using the wrong parameters?).

Here is the thing:

I'm planning to implement a REST webservice using PHP. This webservice is supposed to serve a mobile app and also a website (located on the same server/virtualhost/whatever).

For example, URLs will be something like:

- http://www.somedomain.com/API/ (RESTful webservice)
- http://www.somedomain.com/ (WebSite, which will fetch data from the same sources that the webservice uses).

Now my question is:

Which type of query is the most recommended for querying the database? For example, if I login from the website (http://www.somedomain.com/), it would be better to implement another internal PHP API for that or to login using cURL to the REST API and why?

I know, if I implement another PHP function for login from the website, I will be using one less HTTP connection to my server, but wouldn't it break the idea of the RESTful API?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't add any complexity just for the sake of using the latest trend in web technologies. Both your app and your website should be just fine using a web service. Adding a RESTful layer, just for the sake of using the technology is not the correct way to go about things.

Comment: Nonetheless, use [oAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) for implement authentication on your web site.

Comment: Thank you, CaptainSkyhawk and Max. Really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you want to leave out the HTTP round-trip where you can. That's potentially extremely wasteful, though if the calls are rare then it may be worth it for the code de-deduplication. It all depends on your application really.

Don't worry too much about "breaking the RESTful API" — by your logic, your own application should have no function calls and just be full of `curl` invocations to itself. No, instead, at some point, your code needs to shake off the management speak and just get down to bloody work. :)

Comment: Exactly what I was doing, I was just feeling a bit uncomfortable with this way, but seems a legit one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure most of you know this, but for the sake of completeness:

A function or procedure is a designated program-section that handles a specific task and usually consists out of a function declaration or definition and a function body.

When a function is called remotely, it is known as a remote procedure call (RPC), and the invocation implementation as a Remote Procedure, which is generally handled by an RPC- [API and in rare cases by an ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784389/difference-between-api-and-abi/3784697#3784697).

So at the heart of your quest lies questioning the necessity for remote procedure invocation, and how much a given procedure should perform. As such heeding good **code-refactoring** guidlines is a good start to a good API. I generally adhere to the following pointers:

- If you do not need the necessity of remote invocation for a given procedure, do not expose it unnecessarily.
- Choose wisely which procedures you make API accessible and unit-test them.
- Create various wrapper functions which successively call a set of local functions to perform specific tasks as opposed to calling each function remotely, and render them accessible to the REST API.

An **initial authentication procedure** is a good idea, but I would recommend using established protocols such as **[OAuth](http://www.yworks.com/en/imageviewer.php?img=../img/ygucd/oaupf.graphml&album=ygucd&fs=1) 2** rather than implementing your own. As such may end up using curl in your remote php script.

[This](https://code.google.com/p/simple-php-oauth/) should get you started.

Other than that you do not provide enough information to give you a more specific answer. I would generally recommend to look at [google](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest), [yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/web-services-intro.html), [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/), and perhaps NCBI's [PUG](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug_rest/PUG_REST.html) to see how they implement their REST APIs, which are often a good case-study.

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted this because the great explanation and a good amount of references. I had to accept Lightness' answer because that's exactly what I was asking for, but, as I said, this is a really good lecture. Thanks again!