# Is it legal to assign a restricted pointer to another pointer, and use the second pointer to modify the value?

Tags: c, c99, restrict-qualifier

Does the following method respect the "restrict" contract?

```
void fun(int* restrict foo) {
     int* bar = foo + 32;
     for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
         *bar = 0;
}
```

My guess is no, but I need some clarification.

Comment: Please try to minimize examples, this one would likely be equivalent to: `int* bar = foo + 5; {*bar = 0};` ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it sure respects the contract.

> #### 6.7.3 Type qualifiers
>
> 8 An object that is accessed through a **`restrict`**-qualified pointer has a special association
>   with that pointer. This association, defined in 6.7.3.1 below, **requires that all accesses to
>   that object use, directly or indirectly, the value of that particular pointer.135)** The intended
>   use of the restrict qualifier (like the register storage class) is to promote
>   optimization, and deleting all instances of the qualifier from all preprocessing translation
>   units composing a conforming program does not change its meaning (i.e., observable
>   behavior).

In short, at the point `foo` is defined (the function-call), `foo` is **guaranteed by the programmer** to be the only way to refer to the objects (if any) it points to.
All other expressions referring to those object must thus be derived from that pointers value (like `bar` which is set to `foo+32`).
Breaking faith is, as always in such cases, duly punished by undefined behavior.

Comment: Bravo! Excellent explanation.

Comment: I don't think there's any requirement that it be the only way to refer to the objects, but rather that (1) the sequencing of reads made via a restrict pointer or copy thereof may be arbitrarily moved back in time as far as the point where the restrict pointer was created; (2) the sequencing of writes made via a restrict pointer or copy thereof may be arbitrarily deferred as long as the original restrict pointer is in scope.  If a function receives two `restrict` pointers as parameters, passing the same address to both would be legitimate if no part of an object which is written using one...

Comment: ...is accessed using the other.