# What's wrong with register keyword in C++?

Tags: c++, cpu-registers, c++17, storage-class-specifier

I was reading [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4340.html) and it says that the `register` keyword will most probably be removed from the next C++ standard. It also says that `register` was deprecated in 2011.  So, what's wrong with `register` storage class specifier?

I think modern compilers are very smart and they implicitly optimize frequently used variables for speed (fast access) and puts them in CPU registers.

However, C++ experts also say don't or never use `register`.  As such, what's the problem with the `register` keyword?

Comment: I think you already answered: it was only a recommendation for compiler and compiler better can optimize the storage of a variable.

Comment: It is a useless and sometimes misleading hint. (Kind of like how `inline` no longer means the function will be inline, only that it can be defined multiple times safely).

Comment: Consider the other side: what if an implementation actually put every `register` variable in a register? How could that be handled? Some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928674/can-an-implementation-consider-hints-as-actual-statements).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've pretty much answered your own question:

> I think modern compilers are very smart so they implicitly optimizes frequently used variables for speed (fast access) & puts them in CPU register.

That's precisely the point—optimisers are so good at register allocation nowadays that any attempt from the programmer to enforce their will through the `register` keyword would likely lead to a pessimisatin, and is therefore simply ignored by the compiler. Remember that `register` was never a binding requirement, always just a hint to the compiler. Now that they rightfully scoff at such hints, the keyword is simply obsolete and useless.

So, to directly answer your question of "what's wrong with it:" it no longer serves any purpose whatsoever, as the only one it ever had ("hint to the compiler to put this thing in a register") is now superseded by the compilers being *way* better at this than humans.

Answer (score 1):

Standard doesn't require that `register` variable to be put into registers, instead it's just a hint for compiler for variables that are *often used*. And compiler can determine it on its own.

Here, clause regarding `register` keyword from the link you posted:

> A `register` specifier is a hint to the implementation that the variable so declared will be heavily used. [ *Note*: The hint can be ignored and in most implementations it will be ignored if the address of the variable is taken. This use is deprecated (see D.2). -- *end note* ]