# Function call with pointer to non-const and pointer to const arguments of same address

Tags: c++, c, constants, undefined-behavior

I want to write a function that input an array of data and output another array of data using pointers.

I'm wondering what is the result if both `src` and `dst` pointed to the same address because I know compiler can optimize for const. Is it undefined behavior? (I tagged both C and C++ because I'm not sure if the answer may differ between them, and I want to know about both.)

```
void f(const char *src, char *dst) {
    dst[2] = src[0];
    dst[1] = src[1];
    dst[0] = src[2];
}

int main() {
    char s[] = "123";
    f(s,s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

In addition to above question, is this well-defined if I delete the `const` in original code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While it is true that the behavior is well-defined - it is *not* true that compilers can "optimize for const" in the sense that you mean.

That is, a compiler is *not* allowed assume that just because a parameter is a `const T* ptr`, the memory pointed to by `ptr` will not be changed through another pointer. The pointers don't even have to be equal. The `const` is an obligation, not a guarantee - an obligation by you (= the function) not to make changes through that pointer.

In order to actually have that guarantee, you need to mark the pointer with the `restrict` keyword. Thus, if you compile these two functions:

```
int foo(const int* x, int* y) {
    int result = *x;
    (*y)++;
    return result + *x;
}

int bar(const int* x, int* restrict y) {
    int result = *x;
    (*y)++;
    return result + *x;
}
```

the `foo()` function must read twice from `x`, while `bar()` only needs to read it once:

```
foo:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        add     DWORD PTR [rsi], 1
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]  # second read
        ret
bar:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        add     DWORD PTR [rsi], 1
        add     eax, eax              # no second read
        ret
```

See this live on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/NnG9dP).

`restrict` is only a keyword in C (since C99); unfortunately, it has not been introduced into C++ so far (for the poor reason that it is more complicated to introduce in C++). Many compilers do kinda-support it, however, as `__restrict`.

Bottom line: The compiler must support your "esoteric" use case when compiling `f()`,  and will not have any problem with it.

---

<sub>See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/745870/1593077) regarding use cases for `restrict`.</sub>

Comment: `const` is not “an obligation by you (= the function) not to make changes through that pointer”. The C standard permits the function to remove `const` via a cast and then modify the object through the result. Essentially, `const` is just advisory and a convenience to the programmer to help avoid modifying an object inadvertently.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It's an obligation you can get out of.

Comment: An obligation you can get out of is not an obligation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: 1. You're splitting hairs here. 2. That's not true.

Comment: This is why `memcpy` and `strcpy` are declared with `restrict` arguments, while `memmove` is not -- only the latter allows overlap between the memory blocks.

Comment: Additionally, it is incorrect that `const` is an obligation not to make changes through that pointer. The code `int x = 3; foo(&x); … void foo(const int *p) { * (int *) p = 4; }` is permissible and defined by the C standard.

Comment: Please don't repeat yourself; I've already addressed this point.

Comment: @einpoklum: No, the answer states “a compiler is not allowed assume that just because a parameter is a `const T* ptr`, the memory pointed to by `ptr` will not be changed through another pointer.” It does not state that the compiler is not allowed to assume that the memory pointed to by `ptr` will not be changed through `ptr` itself. This is a different point.

Comment: Changes through `ptr` itself do not involve the compiler assuming anything - it just sees those happening. The example you gave is a way to get around the obligation - that's the cast.

Comment: @einpoklum: Suppose that the address of an automatic `int` is taken in only one place, where it is assigned to `int const *restrict p` which has the same scope and lifetime.  A compiler would be able to infer that the object won't be modified except via the original lvalue, *even if the pointer was passed to a function it knew nothing about.  Such inference would not be possible without the combination of `const` and `restrict`.

Comment: @supercat: In the case you describe, the compiler would _not_ be able to make that inference, since it would be an invalid one. the "function it knows nothing about" can modify the object despite taking it as `const`.

Comment: @einpoklum: If a pointer is qualified `const *restrict`, no pointer based upon it may access any object whose value would change during its lifetime.  From paragraph 4 of N1570 6.7.3.1: "If L is used to access the value of the object X that it designates, and X is also modified (by any means), then the following requirements apply: T shall not be const-qualified."  So if a restrict pointer's type is const-qualified, modification to an object accessed through a pointer derived from it would imply a violation of that constraint.

Comment: @supercat: What are L, X and T?

Comment: @einpoklum: `L` is an lvalue derived from a `restrict`-qualfiied pointer.  `T` is the type of object the pointer is declared as identifying.  `X` is the object designated by the lvalue  `L`.

Comment: @supercat: So, are you saying [this](https://godbolt.org/z/LdZBgZ) is not a valid program? And that gcc is wrong not to emit an error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209730/discussion-between-einpoklum-and-supercat).

Answer (score 5):

This is well-defined (in C++, not sure in C any more), with and without the `const` qualifier.

The first thing to look for is the strict aliasing rule<sup>1</sup>. If `src` and `dst` points to the same object:

- in C, they must be of [compatible types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type); `char*` and `char const*` are not compatible.
- in C++, they must be of [similar types](http://eel.is/c++draft//expr#conv.qual); `char*` and `char const*` are similar.

Regarding the `const` qualifier, you might argue that since when `dst == src` your function effectively modifies what `src` points to, `src` shouldn't be qualified as `const`. This is not how `const` works. Two cases need to be considered:

1. When an object is defined to be `const`, as in `char const data[42];`, modifying it (directly or indirectly) leads to Undefined Behaviour.
2. When a reference or pointer to a `const` object is defined, as in `char const* pdata = data;`, one can modify the underlying object provided it has not been defined as `const`<sup>2</sup> (see 1.). So the following is well-defined:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int result = 42;
    int const* presult = &result;
    *const_cast<int*>(presult) = 0;
    return *presult; // 0
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/5470596)
<sup>2)</sup> [Is `const_cast` safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/357600/5470596)

Comment: Maybe the OP means possible reordering of the assignments?

Comment: `char*` and `char const*` are not compatible. `_Generic((char *) 0, const char *: 1, default: 0))` evaluates to zero.

Comment: The phrasing “When a reference or a pointer to a `const` object is defined” is incorrect. You mean that when a reference or pointer to a `const`-qualified **type** is defined, that does not mean the object it is set to point to may not be modified (by various means). (If the pointer does point to a `const` object, that means the object is indeed `const` by definition, so the behavior of trying to modify it is not defined.)

Comment: @Eric, I'm only that specific when the question is about Standard or tagged `language-lawyer`. Exactitude is a value I cherish, but I'm also aware it comes with more complexity. Here, I decided to go for simplicity and easy-to-understand sentences, because I beleive this is wat OP wanted. If you think otherwise please do answer, I'll be amongst the first to upvote it. Anyway, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

This is well-defined in C. Strict aliasing rules do not apply with the `char` type, nor with two pointers of the same type.

I'm not sure what you mean by "optimize for `const`". My compiler (GCC 8.3.0 x86-64) generates the exact same code for both cases. If you add the `restrict` specifier to the pointers, then the code generated is slightly better, but that won't work for your case, the pointers being the same.

(C11 §6.5 7)

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>   — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>   — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>   — a character type.

In this case (without `restrict`), you will always get `121` as a result.