# I want to split a string into two strings in C

Tags: c, string, loops, split, strtok

I want to split a string by the comma and separate the first number in the string into its own new string, the rest of the string I want to keep together.

So far I have tried this by using `strtok()` and I can get the first number into its own string, but now I can't figure out how to keep the rest of the string together.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char testStr[] = "1000,first,second,third,+abc";
    char *uidStr;
    char *restOfstr;
    int n;

    //This is wrong, I know, but I want to populate 
    //the rest of the string after the first comma
    //into a single string without the UID.
    uidStr = strtok(testStr, ",");
    while (n < 5)
    {
        restOfstr = strtok(NULL, ",");
        n++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: add error-checking, validation, **indentation** -- `char *comma; int n = strtol(testStr, &comma, 10); printf("n: %d + rest is '%s'", n, comma + 1);` see https://ideone.com/TGR2V1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok` works fine, you have to keep in mind that it returns a pointer to each tokenized word so you need two pointers one for the first token and other for the rest of the string.

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y51aTnVaZeFvQgwh)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char testStr[] = "1000,first,second,third,+abc";

    char *uidStr;       //pointer to uid
    char *restOfstr;    //pointers to the rest of the string

    uidStr = strtok(testStr, ",");  //uid remains in testStr
    restOfstr = strtok(NULL, "\n"); //rest of the string

    puts(uidStr); //or puts(testStr) to print uid
    puts(restOfstr); //print rest of the string

    return 0;
}
```

If you want a more secure function you can use [`strtok_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: i did not DV, but i think we do not need to split all of string. Because if the length of string is so long, we will waste time for splitting the rest of this string.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31, yes, it has hapened and it will happen again, normally I don't give too much importance, but it's not in the spirit of the site, if one doesn't like an answer its nice to say why so the answer can be improved.

Comment: @anastaciu (also @OP), A look at the documentation was enough, instead of asking the question.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31, indeed, but it's ok, it's a quirky function, a beginner might not be able to fully understand how to make it work.

Comment: Yep. I agree :)

Comment: Does restOfstr have a null terminator? If I were to pass this as an argument how does it now when its hit the end of this string?

Comment: @ldd12345, yes, strtok replaces the delimiter with a null terminator, in this case, `\n` will be replaced by `\0`. just as in `uidStr` the `,` is rplaced by `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strchr` to find the first comma in the string.

Then using `strncpy` to get the number in the string.

The complete code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "1000,first,second,third,+abc";
    char *s = strchr(str, ',');
    if(!s)
       return -1;
    char num[10];
    strncpy(num, str, s-str);
    num[s-str] = '\0';
    int a = strtol(num, NULL, 10);
    printf("num = %d\nthe remaining: %s\n", a, s+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This gave me 0 when I printed a

Comment: It works fine. Try the test by using the online compiler https://onlinegdb.com/BJ9YtWj98

Comment: @ldd12345 did you copy and paste my code before testing ?

Comment: It worked, I'm not sure what happened. I appreciate you giving that link to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int ac, char **av) {

        while (--ac) {
                char *p = *++av;
                char *t = strtok(p, ",");
                char *r = strtok(NULL,"");
                printf("%s : %s\n", t, r);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Note that the empty string "" passed to the second strtok means that it cannot find a deliminator, thus returns the rest of the string.

Comment: Umm... If I do `char* p = "1000, er,rt";`, then the function doesn't work... What am I missing?

Comment: You would be attempting to modify a string literal; did you get bus error?  Try char _p[] = "1000, er, rt", *p = _p;

Comment: `char* p = "1000, er,rt";` creates the string literal `"1000, er,rt"` and stores the address that points to the first character's position in the pointer p, the string literal is a constant and can't be changed, so assignment attempts will fail. You could do `char p[] = "1000, er,rt";` instead, which makes an array of length 12 and initializes it with the string `"1000, er,rt"`, and you would be able to make assignments.

Comment: Thanks @isrnick. What I fail to understand is, why was `char *r = strtok(NULL,"");` needed? One could have simply done `char* r = p`

Comment: Strtok removes redundant copies of delimiters; so if you want 1000,,,hello to yield "1000" and "hello", the strtok does this; otherwise, t + strlen(t) + 1, would give you the residual.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 No, those two statements do not produce the same result. It is actually the `t` pointer in `char *t = strtok(p, ",");` that is not strictly necessary, since it will end up that `t == p`, so you could print `p` directly.

Comment: I realised that late, and included it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent answers @mevets and @anastaciu have provided (I would go with these), this code will also work fine.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char _p[] = "1000,Hey,There";
    char* str1 = strtok(_p, ",");
    char* str2 = strtok(NULL, "");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask if you need clarification :)

Comment: Note that `p`. `_p` and `str1` all have `"1000"`, the rest of the string is lost.

Comment: As you pass it as an argument to `strtok` the const qualifier is discarded because the `strtok` parameter is `char *__restrict __s`.

Comment: No need to DV, it's almost there, you just need a small adjustment.

Comment: There you go, it fine now. I would just remove `char* p = _p;` since its not serving any purpose.

Comment: @anastaciu, Umm..Will you please explain what __restrict actually does and how it is used? I am clueless -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/extension-restrict?view=vs-2019

Comment: Go no further than SO, usually the best explanations are right here https://stackoverflow.com/a/745877/6865932